# Access to Label value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to access to a value in a checkbox, the atribute value has content, so i need to place the id somewhere else i created a label, but i have not access to that value

```
alert(check[i].label); // doesnt work
```

where else can i place a value in checkbox.
Please dont write that i can do this

```
  <input type='checkbox' id='bla' name='mybla' vlaue='myvalue'> Hy
```

Where can i place some other values ?

I tryed with this

```
<input type='checkbox' id='bla' name='mybla' vlaue='myvalue' label='myothervalue'> Hy
```

first i get all checkbox ect... and in the for loop i did this

```
alert(check[i].label); // doesnt work
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible to store the extra data as a custom attribute on the `<input>` element. When you want to read the value, you can do it like this:

```
alert(check[i].getAttribute('label'));
```

Since you have tagged the question jQuery, here's the trendy version:

```
alert($(check[1]).attr('label'));
```

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600106/storing-arbitrary-info-in-html-tags-for-javascript) [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928369/what-are-the-concrete-risks-of-using-custom-html-attributes) if you are woried about using custom HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

When I am being tempted to do this, I prefer to use a related `hidden` element to store the "other value". It feels cleaner to me, and I also don't have to wade through the validation warnings that otherwise could come at me.
Is that something you can use here?