# jQuery - who really clicked me?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axaqer/5/edit)** ( prev [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801729/passing-data-to-a-jquery-click-function) didn't help much)

```
<span id="mySpan" > click here </span>
  <br/> 
  <input id="myCb" type="checkbox"/>
```

[image]

i have a listener for `checkbox` click which do `Alert`...

However , clicking on the `span` is *triggering* the `click` event for the `checkbox`.

I want to detect - who really made the checkBox  execute the alert.

**But** !

I want :
if first clicked the span , alert
 <kbd>*i was originally pressed by mySpan*</kbd>

else

if first clicked the checkbox , alert  <kbd>*i was originally pressed by myCb*</kbd>

```
$("#mySpan").on('click',function (e) 
  {
    $("#myCb").trigger('click');

  });

$("#myCb").on('click',function (e) 
  {
    doWork(e)
  });


function doWork(e)
{
  alert('i was originally pressed by '+$(e.delegateTarget).attr('id') );
 }
```

p.s. i can use a global field or flag solution  - which i DONT WANT.

i will be glad to have a "moving the data" through the `e` param - solution.

thanks.:)

### edit

jQuery does support moving data , but i cant write the right code

[image]

Comment: theres a jsbin...(first sentence)

Comment: it's best you put the html here. if that link goes dead, the question won't be beneficial to future posters.

Comment: @RoyiNamir way after I have question him ... to many edits!

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer ok . i will edit.

Comment: @RoyiNamir is there any chance you can tell us what are you trying to do in the first place, maybe there's a better way to accomplish all this, maybe you're seeing it from the wrong perspective... would be nice to help you with the correct way, and not only a simple answer, no?

Comment: @balexandre i can press span , i can press checkbox. the checkbox can doWork. somethimes i need the span to do the same work as checkbox click does. BUT inside doWork - i need to know that it came from the span and not from the pure checkbox.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, Do look at my code, I think, thats the one you want ;)

Comment: @Jashwant i did. the +1 is from me. im waiting for more answers. but this is the closest to my question indeed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this.

```
$("#mySpan").on('click',function (e) 
  {

    $("#myCb").trigger(e);

  });

$("#myCb").on('click',function (e) 
  {
    doWork(e);
  });


function doWork(e)
{
  alert('i was originally pressed by '+$(e.target).attr('id') );
 }
```

It worked for me and it was the closest to your original code.

in action http://jsbin.com/ixanup/2/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 2):

This works for me,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mySpan").on('click',function (e){
            $("#myCb").trigger('click','span');
        });

        $("#myCb").on('click',function (e,span){
            var ele = span || 'cb'; 
            doWork(ele);
        });
        function doWork(ele){
          alert('i was originally pressed by ' + ele  );
         } 
    })


</script>
</head> 
<body>
  <span id="mySpan"   style="width:100px;height:100px;" > click here </span>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <input id="myCb" type="checkbox"/>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/elibid/edit#source/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mySpan, #myCb").on('click', function (e) {
    alert('I was originally pressed by ' + e.target.id);
    console.log($(e.target)); /* jQuery reference to the clicked element */

    if (e.target.id === 'myCb') {
       /* do code only if checkbox was clicked */
    }
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4AVZz/

Comment: i dont want the span to have functions code. i just want it to execute the code for checkbox.

Comment: then just wrap inner function with `if (e.target.id === 'myCb')...`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code helpful for you:

```
  $("#mySpan").on('click',function (e) 
  {
    alert('i was originally pressed by '+$(e.delegateTarget).attr('id') );
    if($("#myCb").attr('checked')=="checked")
        $("#myCb").removeAttr('checked');
    else
        $("#myCb").attr('checked','checked');

  });

  $("#myCb").on('click',function (e) 
  {
    alert('i was originally pressed by '+$(e.delegateTarget).attr('id') );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mySpan").on('click',function () {
        var cb = $("#myCb");
        if(cb.is(':checked')) {
            cb.removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            cb.attr('checked', true);
        }
        doWork.apply($(this));
      });

    $("#myCb").on('click',function (e) {
        doWork.apply($(this));
    });
    function doWork(e) {
        console.log('i was originally pressed by '+$(this).attr('id') );
        alert('i was originally pressed by '+$(this).attr('id') );
    }
```

I've modified your example as per your requirement. And saved as a new version.

Please have a look at this. http://jsbin.com/axaqer/7/edit

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$(function() {

  $('.row span, .row input[type="checkbox"]')
    .on('click', function (evt) {

      triggerCheckbox($(this), evt.currentTarget.tagName);
      doWork(evt.currentTarget.tagName);
  });

});

function doWork(elm) {
  // elm with either be INPUT or SPAN
  console.log('I was originally pressed by ' + elm);
}

function triggerCheckbox(elm, evt) {  
  // if it's a SPAN, let's change the checkbox value without
  //  triggering the click event
  if(evt.currentTarget.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    var ckb = $(elm).closest('.row').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $(ckb).prop('checked', !$(ckb).prop('checked'));
  }
}
```

and it will not matter what `ID` you have, it will work with all, as long as you have a wrapper grouping the both.

in HTML, I added a `<div>` to wrap your content, so it will look like:

```
  <div class="row">

    <span id="mySpan">click here</span>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <input id="myCb" type="checkbox"/>

  </div>
```

live example can be [found on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/efahek/edit#javascript,live) as well.

Answer (score -1):

why dont you use,

```
e.currentTarget
```

?

Comment: i tried currentTarget but when i click on the span - it shows `i was originally pressed by myCb`