# Is it possible to append to a div with a given attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do you append to a specific div with a specified attribute?

ex.

```
<div attribute="234"></div>

$('#divwithattribute234').append('test');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading this post about [using custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994856/so-what-if-custom-html-attributes-arent-valid-xhtml) because that wouldn't be valid even in HTML5 which will allow custom attributes. Why not simply use a class since you can have as many as you want ?

```
<div class"some_class some_other_class target_class"></div>
```

Of all the above classes, assuming 'target_class' is the one used for identifying the `<div>`, you would select it and append to it with

```
$(".target_class").html('test');
```

---

**Update:**

If you have more than one target `<div>`s and you're looking for a specific one, use a wildcard selector on the trigger (in our case we'll use the `^=` operator which means 'starts with') and then assign its ID to a variable which we then pass to the `<div>` selector. Say you want to add your text to a `div` when a link is clicked ...

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="some_class" id="target_div_1">Add to DIV 1</a><br />
<a href="#" class="some_class" id="target_div_2">Add to DIV 2</a><br />
<a href="#" class="some_class" id="target_div_3">Add to DIV 3</a><br />

<div class="some_other_class target_1">Div 1</div>
<div class="some_other_class target_1">Div 2</div>
<div class="some_other_class target_1">Div 3</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a[id^=target_div_]").click(function(event) {
    var targetID = $(this).attr('id').substr(11);
    $("div.target_" + targetID).html('content got inserted in div ' + targetID);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMEqm/).

Hope this helps !

Comment: sure you can set as many classes as you want, but the reason I use a custom attribute, is so multiple values can be taken from a div if you have class=1 class=2 how do u find a specific value?

Comment: You can always use a wildcard selector ;) Please see my updated answer, I've also included a JSFiddle live example.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, please leave the first portion of your answer intact so I can use for future reference. However, I was thinking more in the terms of value holding such as <div value="2" id="4"></div>. In another example, what if you wanted to use a div and jquery ajax script to send information to a php script, instead of using a form, you use the value holding div and access its attributes. Is there a substitution for that as well?

Comment: Glad to be of help. The approach that you're proposing is flawed to begin with since `<div>` elements are really not meant to hold values that way. If you insist on placing values inside `<div>`s, give them a `display:none;` attribute and at least do it like `<div id="id_4">2</div>` and retrieve that value with something like `$("div#id_4").html();`. But then again, why don't you use hidden form elements instead since this is what they're meant for ? Something like `<input type="hidden" name="id_4" value="2">`.

Comment: i guess your right, but I was thinking in terms of optimizing and reducing code, so that is why I thought div values was cleaner

Comment: To be honest, in terms of "cleaner" I would personally rather see properly indented code more than anything else. As for optimization, whatever you would win in HTML syntax (although as you probably figured out by now, I wouldn't call invalid syntax a "win"), you would lose in jQuery when writing static triggers for each and every div that you use as opposed to one that uses dynamic selectors. Either way, I'm glad I was able to convince you that good syntax is good and thank you for accepting my answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('div[attribute=234]').html('test');
```

[Check on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KACUL/)

Comment: you are both right but I like the interactive example, thanks naveed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you will match your div (`<div attribute="234"></div>`):

```
$("div[attribute=234]").html('Lets write something...');
```