# XHTML: Adding `custom` attributes

Tags: xhtml, attributes

Is it "ok" to add attributes to various tags to use in JavaScript DOM parsing?

For example if I want to have required fields in a form, would it be a bad practice if I would do this:

```
<input type="submit" name="name" required="true"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: See [
Custom attributes - Yay or nay?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay) and [
So what if custom HTML attributes aren't valid XHTML?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994856/so-what-if-custom-html-attributes-arent-valid-xhtml).

Comment: Excellent, Matthew. Thanks. Either paste that as an answer for me to set it as the answer or someone delete my question.

Answer (score 1):

From that question:

HTML 5 explicitly allows custom attributes that begin with `data`. So, for example, `<p data-date-changed="Jan 24 5:23 p.m.">Hello</p>` is valid. Since it's officially supported by a standard, I think this is the best option for custom attributes. And it doesn't require you to overload other attributes with hacks, so your HTML can stay semantic.

Source:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: Thanks. At that time I wasn't using HTML5. So the correct answer would be, "no, it is not valid XHTML".