# jQuery selector: Firefox recognize but IE not

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This is my element with a custom attribute:

```
<input type="radio" status="B" name="OPT_PARENT"/>
```

**My script:**
Alert($(this).attr("status"));
Alert($(this).attr("test"));

**Output:**
Firefox 3.0.10 --> "B" and "undefined"
IE 8.0.7600.16385 --> "true" and "undefined"

**My observation:**
IE will return the option button "checked state" which is true/false not the custom attribute value. But IE is definitely can detect whether the custom attribute exist.

**My question:**
How to get my custom attribute value in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround for IE, using outerHTML

```
var status = 
   ($(this)
    .get(0)
    .outerHTML
    .replace(/^.+?\bstatus\s*=\s*(?:['"])(\w+).*$/, 
       function(tag, valueattr) {
          return valueattr;
       })) || '';
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps a better option would be to use jquery's [Data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) which allows you to attach data to DOM objects without modifying them with invalid/custom attributes.

i imagine this would eliminate the browser incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using custom attributes is generally a bad idea and what you have isn't valid even in HTML5 which is supposed to allow custom attributes. Why not pass any extra info as a class or as an ID ? You could have something like

```
<input type="radio" id="extra_A" name="OPT_PARENT"/>
<input type="radio" id="something_B" name="OPT_PARENT"/>
<input type="radio" id="extra_C" name="OPT_PARENT"/>
```

The reason I prefixed it is so that it would be easier to select just the elements that you need:

```
$("input[id^=extra_]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id').substr(6));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is my old style. somehow i dont like it coz of the substr. I havent study bout HTML5 so i'll take a look on what do you mean by "isn't valid even in HTML5". Thank you for ur comment.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/994856/230354) for more info. As for `.substr()` there's nothing wrong in using it, and as opposed to custom attributes, it won't invalidate your markup. Either way, glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Somehow my friends told me that "status" is probably a **non-custom** attribute. So after change "status" --> "myStatus" my code work well.