# DOCTYPE [XHTML 1.0 Transitional] does not validate if a custom attribute is present

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml, doctype

I use DOCTYPE XHTML 1 Transitional, I have a `<a>` with a custom attribute  with name `data-reveal-id`, this attribute is used by a jQuery script.

I'm not able to validate the document using W3, as `data-reveal-id` is not XHTML valid.

Any idea how to solve it?

Many thanks for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
...

   <a href="#" data-reveal-id="modal-portfolio-awards">View</a>
```

Error when validating with W3

```
there is no attribute "data-reveal-id" [XHTML 1.0 Transitional]
```

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994856/so-what-if-custom-html-attributes-arent-valid-xhtml.

Comment: Is the file an actual XHTML file (served up with the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type, etc.) If not, don't use an XHTML DOCTYPE declaration. Problem solved!

Comment: @Mr Lister — The document will still be invalid, but browsers will render it using Quirks mode. Problem not solve but new problems created.

Comment: @Quentin I meant to use the HTML5 one, of course. Silly!

Comment: I solved using HTML 5 DOCTYPE thanks Mr Lister to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Don't use custom attributes

Option 2: Use (X)HTML 5 (which allows custom attributes that start `data-`)

Comment: Option 3: Add a namespace and prefix the custom attribute with the namespace prefix.

Comment: @Oded — Still invalid. You would have to change the DTD to allow the second namespace. At that point you aren't writing XHTML 1.0 Transitional any more. You are writing XHTML 1.0 Transitional + Attributes From Some Other Namespace