# how to check field name of a td with jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, html-table

I have the value in an td attribute 'field', but I can not find a proper way to check or validate its value.

i.e.

```
<td class="edit" field="qcat_id" user_id="1">MyCat</td>
```

The way I tried:

```
function makeEditable(element) { 
    console.log (element);
        if (element.field =="qcat_id"){
            alert('yes');
        }
}
```

It will never show yes, and the `console.log` returns the whole `<td>...</td>` as string.

Update======================
Below is the code where gather the `element` parameter

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("dblclick", "td.edit", function(){ makeEditable(this); });
});
```

Thank you all

Comment: what code do you use to define 'element' variable?

Comment: You should use `data-` attributes for this

Comment: @RGraham Interesting, would you elaborate the reason for it? thanks!

Comment: There are a number of justifications for not using custom attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994856/so-what-if-custom-html-attributes-arent-valid-xhtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With JQuery it should just be as follows:

```
if (element.attr("field") =="qcat_id"){
    alert('yes');
}
```

This assumes that `element` is a JQuery object, if not you need to get that using an appropriate selector, something like:

```
var element = $(".edit");
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EYUC4/)

---

As RGraham has suggested, it would be better to use `data-*` attributes for storing this kind of data. You can do that like so:

```
<td class="edit" data-myid="qcat_id" user_id="1">MyCat</td>
```

Which can be retrieved with the following:

```
var myId = $(".edit").data("myid");
```

[Here is an example using data attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/EYUC4/1/)

Comment: I encounter error of "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'data' " Do you know why this happened?

Comment: @Chen: Instead of `makeEditable(this);` try `makeEditable($(this));` which will convert the element (`this`) into a JQuery object, which has the function `data`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".edit").attr("field")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = $('.edit').attr('field');
   alert(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $("td[user_id='1']");

if (element.attr("field") == "qcat_id"){
    alert('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the attribute as below.

```
$("td[user_id='1']").attr("field");
```

You should prefix the attributes with data-, this is how custom attributes are named. 
Also, all the attributes prefixed by data- are ignored by user agents.