# Show hide div's depending on which link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four links which i need to show hide there corresponding div depending on which one is clicked. Also if the same link is clicked it should hide its corresponding link. All fade fadIn.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/mnotd7Lh/

```
<ul>
        <li><a id="category" href="">Catergory</a></li>
        <li><a id="style" href="">styles</a></li>
        <li><a id="brand" href="">brand</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="one">This is my category</div>
    <div id="two">This is styles</div>
    <div id="three">This is main brands</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#category").click(function(){
  $("#one").fadeToggle();
});

$("#style").click(function(){
  $("#two").fadeToggle();
});
$("#style").click(function(){
  $("#three").fadeToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
#two, #three, #four{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class name ("fading" for instance) to each link that you like to have this behavior and add the related div that should be toggled as an Attribute (`relDiv="one"` for instance). Also add a class to all related divs (`class="relDiv"` for instance).

So your HTML must be look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="fading" relDiv="one" href="">Catergory</a></li>
    <li><a class="fading" relDiv="two" href="">styles</a></li>
    <li><a class="fading" relDiv="three" href="">brand</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="one" class="relDiv">This is my category</div>
<div id="two" class="relDiv">This is styles</div>
<div id="three" class="relDiv">This is main brands</div>
```

And use just this few JQuery lines for as many as menu you want:

```
var currentDiv = 'one';
$(".fading").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    if (currentDiv != $this.attr('relDiv')){
        $("#" + currentDiv).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            $("#" + $this.attr('relDiv')).fadeIn();
        });
    }   
    currentDiv = $(this).attr('relDiv');
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ctfh6jc/2/)**

Comment: Yo! ++1 to you as well, *small reco*  I reckon highlight use of `preventDefault` as well. `:)`.

Comment: Good job adding the `relDiv` attribute and the fading class for simpler code. Wouldn't it be better to use a `data-related-el` element to stick with standards and have your page still validate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994856/so-what-if-custom-html-attributes-arent-valid-xhtml

Comment: In fact in this case he/she can don't use <a> tags at all, it can be done using the `<li>` tags and set the `cursor:pointer` style and we can remove links and `e.preventDefault();`. but i don't do that because think maybe he/she has a reason to use links. although i appreciate you answer for highlighting `preventDefault`.

Comment: @Moshtaf  There should be links so that the page still works without JavaScript. I reckon the OP left them out for simplicity

Comment: This is great, but only one div at a time can be open. And they need have a self closing option as well.

Comment: @JuanMendes: Absolutely you're right, but i don't know that why i don't like this `.data()` attr, it seems that don't work in all situations easily or i miss something, but i'm comfortable with `.attr()` that always works fine !!

Comment: @JuanMendes: Really? if disable javascript, the divs that has `display:none'` class start hide and show if we use links? i must to check that in future.

Comment: @Steve The main question you asked has been answered, you cannot post multiple requirements in a single question. Questions should be about a single problem you're facing. Otherwise, it sounds like: "Please write my code for me"

Answer (score 1):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9ctfh6jc/ or this: http://jsfiddle.net/vm7oLjbd/

- API you need is `preventDefault()` to prevent `a` tags default action.
- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Try this:

```
$("#category").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#one").fadeToggle();
});

$("#style").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#two").fadeToggle();
});
$("#style").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#three").fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: I often see people mistakenly calling `stopEvent` when `preventDefault` will do the job with fewer side effects.

Comment: @JuanMendes progressive learning I reckon `:)` Totally agree with you!

Comment: Close, only problem is it doesnt close the other div once new one is clicked?

Comment: @Steve - > lil verbose here: http://jsfiddle.net/gu5b3mk1/ but I guess above post has a `class` example which is less verbose version `:)` but this demo might do what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/gu5b3mk1/