# What are pros and cons, If I choose HTML 5 for all new projects?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

Everyone, every blog is talking about HTML 5 and [giving solution to use HTML in all browsers including IE6](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/).

- Should we leave XHTML 1.0 now and go
  for HTML 5 and use JavaScript for IE6 support?
- Does all other desktop/mobile browser
  except IE6 supports HTML 5 without
  adding JavaScript?
- Will every browser render CSS written
  for HTML 5 elements?
- What about Screen- readers?

### What are pros and cons to choose HTML 5 for all new projects?

Comment: possible dupes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016515/html-5-early-adoption-where-possible-good-or-bad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188770/is-it-time-to-start-developing-with-html5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186264/is-it-time-to-start-using-html5

Comment: more dupes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933241/is-valid-html5-ok-to-use-now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros:

- It has some nice new features

Cons:

- Support for those features is very thin on the ground
- QA tools are immature compared to those for XHTML and HTML 4.x
- The  spec is still changing

> Should we leave XHTML 1.0 now and go for HTML 5

I wouldn't. I'd stick to HTML 4.01.

> and use JavaScript for IE6 support?

You need JS shims for more than IE6. I think IE8 might still require them - and that's for basic support for things like `<article>` just so you can apply CSS. Forget about `<video>` for the new form stuff.

> Does all other desktop/mobile browser except IE6 supports HTML 5 without adding JavaScript?

No

A quick test shows that IE8 and Firefox 3.6 don't support `<article>` (IE8 doesn't appear to make it available for styling, Firefox styles it as `display: inline` by default)

> Will every browser render CSS written for HTML 5 elements?

Not without JS hacks.

> What about Screen- readers?

Most will not be able to do anything useful with the new elements

Comment: liked your answer. and i will still stay with XHTML. I think pros are not big to use HTML 5 for now. Thanks.and still it's not screen reader compatible.

Comment: although i found a favor in this http://blog.honustudios.com/2010/01/why-we-chose-html5-and-css3/

Answer (score 1):

See also http://html5doctor.com/how-to-use-html5-in-your-client-work-right-now/

Comment: +1 Very very good link. but i think still HTML is not ready for Accessibility

Answer (score 0):

XHTML works with the HTML5 doctype and you need to change nothing as long as you are serving it as application/xml+xhtml and are using the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: that i know , my question is about new HTML elements

Comment: Same answer for new elements.