# jQuery filter through IDs and then capture matches

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, pattern-matching

I find myself doing this repeatedy.

```
$jq("button").filter(function(){
    return this.id.match(/^user_(\d+)_edit$/);
}).click(function(){
    var matches = this.id.match(/^user_(\d+)_edit$/);
    var user_id = matches[1];

    alert('click on user edit button with ID ' + user_id);
});
```

So I want to apply a **click** event to some buttons and in the click event handler I need the user ID. Is there a way I can avoid the second match?

```
$jq("button").filter(function(){
    return this.id.match(/^user_(\d+)_edit$/);
}).click(function(){
    var user_id = some_magic_variable;

    alert('click on user edit button with ID ' + user_id);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about avoiding the first match?

```
$jq("button[id^=user][id$=edit]").click(function() {

});
```

Would select all buttons that have an ID that [starts with](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) user and [ends with](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) edit.

Although honestly, looking at your use case, it would be WAY better to simply give all buttons that are meant to edit a user a class of "edit_user" and then just do:

```
$jq('button.edit_user').click(function() {

});
```

It is cleaner, faster, and the jQuery way of getting all elements that serve a similar purpose.

As far as getting the user id there's been some lively discussion on custom attributes on this site ([Custom attributes - Yay or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay)) and I personally do `data-userid='5'` in my elements and then just do `var id = $(this).attr('data-userid');` to get the ID. Nice and easy. Won't validate as XHTML, though.

Comment: I agree with use of a 'edit_user' class, but I need a user_id link to each button. I could do this <button id="user_12" class="edit_user"/> but I stll need to do match to get the user ID.

Comment: +1 Darn you Paolo...Upvoting you brought me into my last ten votes for the day - 2 or 3 of which were yours. Stop providing insight!

Comment: You can take away the upvote if you'd like, I hit my daily cap like 2 hours ago. I just can't stop! :P

Answer (score 3):

You could store the ID on the element itself (using jQuery's [data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data#namevalue) method) when you do the filter, and then retrieve that value in the click handler.

```
$jq("button").filter(function(){
    var $this = $jq(this);
    var matches = $this.attr('id').match(/^user_(\d+)_edit$/);

    if (matches) {
        $this.data('idNumber', matches[1]);
    }

    return matches;
}).click(function(){
    var user_id = $(this).data('idNumber');

    alert('click on user edit button with ID ' + user_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would preprocess the DOM:

```
$(function() {

$("button").each(function() { 
      var matches = $(this).attr("id").match(/^user_(\d+)_edit$/);

      if (matches) {
         $(this).data("user_edit_id",matches[1]);
      }
   }
});
```

Then you can simply:

```
$("button").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("user_edit_id");
}).click(function(){
    var user_id = $(this).data("user_edit_id");

    alert('click on user edit button with ID ' + user_id);
});
```

It's not a perfect solution to what you want, but it's one way...

Comment: Not really a big fan of this solution as it still takes a bunch of sweeps of all the buttons unnecessarily. At the very least you could add a class on the each if there's matches, chain that together with the click, and avoid the filter function altogether. So: $('button').each(...).filter('.user_edit').click(...);

Comment: True, but I was proposing a solution within the context of the current problem (without changing markup)