# Storing arbitrary info in HTML tags for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

A very general question.

I am dynamically generating a form that is split into multiple levels of tabs using HTML / JavaScript.

I want to highlight some of the fields (those that have a value differing from a global template) with a star * symbol using CSS and background-image.

A JS field iterates through each field, compares its value, and sets a CSS class for it if necessary. So far, so good.

Now in addition, I want not only every changed field to be marked with a star, but also the *tab* it is in.

Because I love it simple, I would like to store the element ID of the tab as an attribute somewhere in each field's HTML tag (something like "parentTab"). The JS function then highlights the field and its "parentTab" element (and maybe that one's "parentTab" as well).

My first approach is to misuse the "title" attribute or somethiong to store parentTab in. Of course, that's dirty. However, if I just wildly add arbitrary attributes to the DIV or INPUT tag, it won't validate any more and I feel less than secure accessing these attributes - who knows how different browsers handle it, and will handle it in the future?

So my question is: Is there a valid, standards compliant way - an attribute of some sort - to store arbitrary data inside HTML tags, for further processing by JavaScript?

Of course, I could create a "parentTabs" JS array and be done with it. But storing it in the input itself would be so much more elegant.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay/992464, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331587/how-should-i-associate-server-side-data-with-client-side-ui-elements-in-html for more on data passing to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find out which tabbed element a field belongs to by writing an isChildOf function, like this: http://jimkeller.blogspot.com/2008/07/jquery-ischildof-is-element-child-of.html

Using the DOM to work this out will always be more "elegant" than duplicating the data in some custom format.

Comment: that requires jQuery, though... But this should also be fairly easy without jQuery.

Comment: "Using the DOM to work this out will always be more "elegant" than duplicating the data in some custom format." - point taken. I will for the moment probably go for the "rel" attribute as it is so quick to do; on the long run, the DOM approach is right.

Answer (score 22):

with the introduction of html5, you can use [attributes that start with `data-`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), and they'll still validate.

```
<input type="text" name="username" data-parentTab="tab1" value="non-default">
```

Comment: Well thats great for the 5-10% of the population that has HTML5 capable browsers.

Comment: Spot on. @OP: **And** you can start using it right away, even though the spec isn't finished.  Just change your doctype declaration to `<DOCTYPE HTML>` (that's the whole thing; HTML5 makes doctypes a *lot* easier to remember).

Comment: @cletus: It won't matter for older browsers, as it isn't really doing anything except hold information. This will work perfectly fine in IE6. It just won't validate as XHTML or HTML4...

Comment: @cletus: Not so, non-HTML5 browsers universally ignore attributes they don't understand, so you can use this technique right now today, safe in the knowledge that it's future-proofed.  Here's some good reading on it: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks for this - this will come in handy in the future.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it's `<!DOCTYPE html>` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `rel` attribute is often a great valid choice for storing data like this.

Comment: True, and I will go with it for the moment. Still, it is blatant misuse of the attribute, I was looking for ways around that :)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you have the Data API for the matter.
http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data

If you do not use jQuery, you can add your own tags and store anything in it.
everybody will tell you this is not nice etc, but all the great web firms are doing so. so you will end up in a great company ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I like how [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) did this: a script tag with arbitrary type. His example is about templating, but you could really use this for anything.