# Correct way for custom HTML attributes

Tags: xhtml, attributes, markup, custom-attributes

I am writing custom form validation javascript library and I am thinking about correct markup syntax. Let's say I have an input that requires number between 1 000 and 10 000.

So far, I came up with something like this:

```
<input class='validate required number' min='1000' max='10000' />
```

Is this correct way to do it? I have two problems here:

1. I don't like using classes. It feels like misuse. Is it OK to use them like this?
2. My custom attributes `min` and `max` don't validate.

Comment: Duplicate or at least related: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600106/storing-arbitrary-info-in-html-tags-for-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) will support this structure, it might be the best way to go:

```
<input data-validate="very-yes" data-min="1000" data-max="10000"/>
```

Whereby any "data-..." attribute can be used to store more info.  You could also attach this data after using script(s)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to use classes like that. In fact, it makes doing things in Javascript and CSS a lot easier.

Custom attributes are not allowed in HTML. The class attribute should be used instead to add custom functionality or style to each tag.

In your case, I would advise adding a class such as "number-1000-10000", and then use Javascript to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) it seems to specify the complicated validation arguments (e.g. max and min values for a field) in JSON format.