# <img> Attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I've got some java script code that implements a kind of slide show. It uses a series of img tags as a table to control its actions.  I probably used some code I found some where as a basis.  Anyway, the img tags contain a data-img attribute which I can't find in any definition of the img tag.  Now I find I need to add more data to the img tags.  So my questions are:

1) Is the data-img actually a real attribute or something adhoc?

2) Can I invent yet more attributes?

3) What is the danger of using such attributes?

Comment: It's valid in HTML 5. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600106/storing-arbitrary-info-in-html-tags-for-javascript

Comment: Why not just use the jQuery carosel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It's valid in HTML 5; it is an invalid attribute (that will, as far as I know, still work in all browsers, it but will break validation) in HTML 4

2) *As far as I am aware*, you can add arbitrary attributes and query them in Javascript, but chances are those attributes will not survive certain DOM manipulation and other operations where the browser creates markup - it's possible the invalid attributes will simply be dropped

3) Your pages will no longer validate.

Background: [Custom attributes - Yay or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay/992464)

Comment: From the reference you cite it seems that perhaps data-anything is ok in HTML 5.  Is that correct?  Also see http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: @Mike data-anything is definitely valid and fine in HTML 5, yes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on implementation.
2. YES, its often quite useful to do so.
3. If created in #2, not really, no, they are part of the DOM at that point, i know of no browser that removes attributes.

Comment: The browser removes attributes that he is not aware of. That means that IE8 and lower have no idea what he is talking about.

Comment: @elusive when does the browser remove unknown attributes? Surely not in a normal HTML / Javascript page context?

Comment: @Pekka: I ran into problems with custom attributes some time ago and figured that it only happened in IE. I am not sure of the context, though.

Answer (score 0):

They are a valid HTML5 attributes.

If you need to add and get that data only with javascript for client side without communicating with the server side you can implement a [store and retrieve](http://mootools.net/blog/2008/01/22/whats-new-in-12-element-storage/) mechanism similar to the one used by Mootools.

It doesn't pollute the DOM and store also javascript objects.