# Is it a good practice when i make a livewire component from the <head> section of a webpage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3, laravel-livewire-wiremodel, laravel-livewire-wireclick

When i make a livewire component from the head section of a webpage, there are some livewire related attributes added to the  tag.

ex:

```
<head wire:snapshot="{&quot;data&quot;:[],&quot;memo&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;MJLBquIJtX34LdqEoZFH&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;front.layouts.partials.app-head&quot;,&quot;path&quot;:&quot;website\/blog&quot;,&quot;method&quot;:&quot;GET&quot;,&quot;children&quot;:[],&quot;scripts&quot;:[],&quot;assets&quot;:[],&quot;errors&quot;:[],&quot;locale&quot;:&quot;nl&quot;},&quot;checksum&quot;:&quot;1137161766be15c799e1439dd1127cafffb3f746382d51a143b2c07cb2f8d5b8&quot;}" wire:effects="[]" wire:id="MJLBquIJtX34LdqEoZFH">
```

Is this a bad practice for SEO ?

Comment: I think these Livewire directives works like custom tag attributes so [they are not problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968212/how-bad-is-it-to-add-custom-attributes-to-html-tags)