# Adding custom attributes in html tags

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom attributes - Yea or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay)

Can any side effect occur in browsers if I add custom attributes to html tags for instance:

```
<a href="" mycustomtag="mydata"></a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No side effects that I know if, they just won't validate and it's possible that in the future whatever attribute name you choose may conflict if browsers decide to implement one with the same name (Unlikely if you name it something unique enough)

Read more here: [Custom attributes - Yea or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay)

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, except that if you try to validate your markup, this will cause it to fail.

Otherwise, from a browser perspective there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone will be kind to you (JavaScript, CSS, HTML) but your page will not validate.

If you decide to use custom attributes, prefix them with `data-` to make them forward compatible with HTML5 (and to not use a possible reserved attribute in the future).

```
<a href="http://example.com" data-myatt="mydata">click?</a>
```