# How do I get custom HTML attribute in jquery each() loop

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="first" expression="firstExpression"/>
 <input type="text" name="last" expression="secondExpression"/>
 <input type="text" name="age" expression="thirdExpression"/>
```

I have a custom **expression** attribute.

I using jQuery to iterate over all the input elements, and although I will need to do something later, I need to be able to grab the expression value for each of these input elements, and compare it to the **value** of that input element.

I am able to grab the expression value by doing the following

```
    var expressionValue = inputs.attr("expression");
```

but that only grabs the expression value of the following, I need to be able to do the same thing such as the following scenario

```
 function showValues()
 {
    var inputs = $(":input[expression]");
    inputs.each(function(index){ 
    var input = inputs[index];
    //need to be able to get 'expression' from input var here 
    });
 }
```

the code above is correctly grabbing all the elements I need, but I am unable to figure out how to grab the value of the expression attribute

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use the `$.each` like this:

```
function showValues()
 {
    var inputs = $("input[expression]");
    console.log(inputs); //output input for debug
    inputs.each(function(){ 
       console.log(this,$(this).attr('expression'));//show expression (for debug)
    });
 }

showValues();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/LmW8P/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$("input[expression]").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('expression'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the attribute value you can optionally pass a `function()` into `.attr()` which will allow you iterate the collection.

```
function showValues() {
    var inputs = $(":input[expression]");
    inputs.attr("expression", function(index, expression){

    });
}
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/rxUQL/)**

Answer (score 0):

try

$(input).attr('expression');//expression

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have the liberty of using HTML5, it would be best to append the word "data-" to the custom attribute as this would not invalidate the document.

More details on [Custom Attributes: Yay or Nay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay)

And w3.org talks about custom attributes in more details and also mentions a dataset property to be able to access all such elements quite easily in script, details on [W3.Org - Using Custom Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Hope this helps!