# Set a text field's value from a span value attribute on JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, textfield

I'm having a little issue, for styling purposes I'm using a Definition list instead of a combobox, inside my dd tag, there's an ul, inside every li, there's a span, with a value attribute. I'm trying to put that value on a text field, so I can use it in a post action. This code is inside the click function of my li:

```
var temp = $(this).find("span").attr("value");
$("#ch").val(temp);
```

I believe my selection is right, because when I log temp's value, it is the one I want, but when I log the ch field's value, I get undefined.

What am I missing? 
Thanks in advance.

José.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#ch").val($(this).find("span").text());
```

However if you're sure `temp` has the correct value (even when using the wrong method), then you're probably not hitting your target, are you sure the element has the ID `ch` ?

Comment: Who in the right mind would give a `value` attribute to a `span` element (per your last update)? `span` elements don't have a `value` attribute unless you define it in the markup yourself.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - who knows, but the question does state that the `temp` variable supposedly contains the right value ?

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed the part that he stated to be getting the right value in `temp`. My point still stands though, could use `data-` attributes or another hundred of better ways around it. Here's some [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992115/1331430) for OP if he is creating custom attributes.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I agree with you, and I had to read the question four times to actually see that it is in fact stated that the `temp` value is right, so that leaves the second line, and there ain't much that go wrong there, other than the selector ?

Comment: Yup, either that or maybe, `#ch` is not an `input` element and thus doesn't have a `value` property to be set with `.val()`? If `#ch` is a `span` for example, `$('#ch').html(temp)` or `$('#ch').text(temp)` should be used.

Comment: Oh nvm my comment above, just made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/n5nBf/) and if the element doesn't have a `value` property, jQuery will create it. Seems like the selector was indeed faulty. +1

Comment: I forgot to put my id attribute on my input, just put the name attribute, there was my mistake. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just to know, `span` elements don't have a `value` attribute unless you define it in the markup yourself.

---

**Possible ways to achieve what you want:**

Use this:

```
$('#ch').val($(this).find('span').html());
```

Or:

```
$('#ch').val($(this).find('span').text());
```

Inside this:

```
$(selector).on('click', function() {
   $('#ch').val($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

**Possible solutions to `undefined` problem:**

- Make sure you are using the correct id for the element you want to set the value.
- Maybe your element `#ch` is in DOM, so you will need to use `.on()` as the above example instead of just `$(selector).click();`