# How to add a new attribute to a tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<input  id="test" value="123" name ="test"  verify="NOTNULL">
```

In some HTML, I saw the `input` tag has the attribute `verify`. How to add it to the input tag?

I tried the code

```
alert(document.getElementById("test").verify)
```

the result is `undefined`.

How do I add a new attribute to the element?

Comment: Adding an attribute to an HTML tag is typically done on the server. Are you saying that the attribute is already on the HTML tag, and you need to extract its value from the JavaScript DOM element?

Comment: Not all HTML attributes map to DOM properties, especially not custom attributes. You should use `data-*` attributes for custom ones. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/992115/218196. Btw, the attribute *is* already added to the element, because you defined it in the HTML. It seems you want to know how to *access* it. If you really want to *add* it programmatically, you can use `setAttribute`.

Comment: ...ah, I see the HTML was unformatted and lost. Yeah, like @Felix said, it would be good to use `data-` attributes instead.

Comment: thank you,i used 'getAttribute' and get the value  of  the verify.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean to say that the html input element has a `[verify]` attribute, then you can access the attribute via `getAttribute()`:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<input id="test" verify="test" />
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('verify'); //test
```

Comment: Note that the `[verify]` attribute is not a valid HTML attribute as far as I'm aware. [`[data-*]` attributes should be used for passing custom attribute values](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Adding an attribute with pure Javascript is done via `setAttribute`

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("verify","verified");
```

And to read it:

```
document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("verify")
```