# Hyphenated html attributes with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a nicer syntax when creating elements with hyphenated attributes instead of using:

```
<%= Html.TextBox ("name", value, new Dictionary<string, object> { {"data-foo", "bar"} }) %>
```

---

Looking at the HTML specs for the proposed standards HTML 5 and [WIA ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) it seems hyphens in HTML attributes are being planned to be more common as some sort of simple name spacing.

E.g. HTML 5 proposes custom attributes are prefixed with `data-` and WIA ARIA uses the `aria-` prefix for all WIA ARIA attributes.

When using HTML helpers in ASP.NET MVC such as `<%= Html.TextBox("name", value, new { attribute = attributeValue }) %>` the anonymous object is converted to a dictionary.

Unfortunately in C# there is no support for hyphens in names, so the only alternative is to create a dictionary. The syntax for which is very verbose, has anyone seen a nicer alternative or a simple way of altering the functionality of ASP.NET MVC's HTML extensions without having to re-write the entire extension?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Use an underscore in the data attribute name, and it'll magically handle it for you, converting it to a hyphen. It knows you want a hyphen rather than an underscore as underscores aren't valid in html attribute names.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name", value, new { @data_foo = "bar"}) %>
```

Comment: I found a similar problemin several SO questions, and this is the best answer.

Comment: Could you add the reason for your statement **underscores aren't valid in html attributes**. At least [html 4.01 states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-attribute): _The attribute value may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons (ASCII decimal 58)_,

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree your quote refers to the attribute value, but in this question we're referring to attribute names.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree I have changed the end of my answer to 'underscores aren't valid in html attribute names'

Answer (score 19):

The answer provided at [ActionLink htmlAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108943/actionlink-htmlattributes) suggests using underscores instead of hyphens.  MVC.Net is supposed to emit hyphens instead of the underscores when sending the page to the browser.