# Html5 data-* with asp.net mvc TextboxFor html attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I add `data-*` html attributes using TextboxFor?

This is what I currently have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country.CountryName, new { data-url= Url.Action("CountryContains", "Geo") })
```

As you see, the `-` is causing a problem here `data-url`. Whats the way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hyphenated html attributes with asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 444, accepted):

You could use underscore (`_`) and the helper is intelligent enough to do the rest:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.Country.CountryName, 
    new { data_url = Url.Action("CountryContains", "Geo") }
)
```

And for those who want to achieve the same in pre ASP.NET MVC 3 versions they could:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.Country.CountryName, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "data-url", Url.Action("CountryContains", "Geo") } 
    }
) %>
```

Comment: Is this behaviour specified anywhere :) ?

Comment: @Rookian, I have no idea if it is specified anywhere. I guess some blog posts over the internet oughta be talking about it.

Comment: @Ryan, no it doesn't because it does't make sense to work for `EditorFor`. The EditorFor helper is used to render a custom HTML template that corresponds to the given type. A template could contain many elements, so talking about attributes in a template doesn't really make sense. Of course you could always write a custom template that works with the `additionalViewData` parameter that could be passed to an editor template and simply output them as attributes on the corresponding input field.

Comment: Just to be clear the resulting markup has an underscore and not hyphen.  The sentence "You could use underscore (_) and the helper is intelligent enough to do the rest", specifically the bit about the supposed intelligence made me believe it would auto convert to - but it doesn't.  HTML5 supports -.

Comment: @AlanMacdonald the `_` is converted to `-` in older (middle?) versions of MVC. It may be that the most recent version(s) have dropped it, but I'm using it successfully on MVC 3 and 4.

Comment: @AlanMacdonald (and others reading), the `_` is converted to `-` in MVC 5, too. I'm using it successfully in a project I'm currently working on, which uses MVC 5.

Comment: It also appears to work with `EditorFor` in MVC 5, at least for a simple string property.

Comment: How to show a text as a hyperlink in the TextBoxFor?  Ex: If I copy-paste any url in this text box then it should show as a hyperlink to navigate that url by clicking. Is it possible in the text box?