# How do I add attributes to an element created with razor helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add attributes like `class`, `style` .etc, using the razor helpers. How can I accomplish this?

Example: `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.First)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the New keyword and you can add HTML attributes like so:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.First, new { @class = "test", id = "Lbl1"}))
```

Etc..You can keep adding HTML attributes inside the new {}.

Comment: You need to prefix `class` with `@` to escape it. It's a C# keyword: `new { @class = "test"...`

Comment: I am getting an error with this approach. The code underline in red

Comment: the problem with this approach is that you can't place `data-` attributes

Comment: @CristiPufu you can use data, but by using **data_*** <br/>
[See this StackOverflow Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844001/html5-data-with-asp-net-mvc-textboxfor-html-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.First, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "class-name" }, { "style", "display:none" } });`

Is that what u mean ?

Comment: I am getting an error with this approach. The code underline in red