# Add property with - in name

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In MVc I am using `Html.TextboxFor()` control

I have input type control as below.

```
<input id="phoneNumber" type="text" class="phoneNumber form-control" value="@actorPhone.PhoneNumber" data-phoneType ="@actorPhone.PhoneTypeTd" data-actorId ="@Model.ActorId" maxlength="30"/>
```

I want to change this intput control to MVC

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.phoneNumber,new {@class = "phoneNumber", maxlength = "30"})
```

How I can add data-phoneType and data-actorId properties to the html control, as - is not allowed in the properties of `HTML Attribute`.

Comment: With all the answers here is another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844001/html5-data-with-asp-net-mvc-textboxfor-html-attributes) using underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an underscore `_`

the Razor engine is smart enough to render the underscore within the property name to the corresponding dash sign, resulting in your desired HTML5-like attributes

example:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.phoneNumber,
    new {@class = "phoneNumber", maxlength = "30", 
    data_phoneType = YOUR_VALUE_HERE,    
    data-actorId=YOUR_VALUE_HERE })
```

and this should result in your desired output.

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set an underscore instead and Razor will render it like a minus/dash:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phoneNumber, 
      new { data_phoneType = "phone type",  
            @class = "phoneNumber", 
            maxlength = "30"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data_*` attributes like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.phoneNumber,
    new {
        data_phoneType=actorPhone.PhoneTypeTd, 
        @class = "phoneNumber", 
        maxlength = "30"
        })
```