# add search functionality on DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wondering if any one could help me with a issue I am facing. I am trying to create a search on a DropDownListFor using razor.

```
private List<SelectListItem> LoadStockitems()
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var role in GetStockItemsFromDB())
    {
        SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem();
        listItem.Value = role.StockCode;
        listItem.Text = role.Description;
        selectItems.Add(listItem);
    }
    return selectItems;
}

ViewBag.AllStockList  = LoadStockitems();
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>
    x.StockCode,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllStockList,
    new {
        @class = "form-control",
        @Value = @Model.Description,
        onchange = "this.form.submit();"
})
```

I can do this using Html but I can not figure out how to do using razor. 
In HTML,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Hello", "Hello"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Select A Customer </label>
        <select class="selectpicker bs-select form-control"
                name="CustomerID"
                onchange="this.form.submit()"
                data-show-subtext="true"
                data-live-search="true">
            @foreach (var Customer in @Model.CustomerSelect)
            {
                <option value="@Customer.CustomerID"
                        data-subtext="@Customer.ContactName">
                    @Customer.Name
                </option>
            }
        <select>
        <input type="hidden" name="SearchButton" value="true">
    </div>
}
```

How can you create a search on a DropDownListFor and is there anything like subtext attribute...?

Comment: How do you do "Search in dropdown" with HTML ? Can you show your code to do that ?

Comment: Check this example: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Searchable-DropDownList-in-ASP-Net-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using a bootstrap plugin called [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search). To use it in razor view, do this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>
    x.StockCode,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllStockList,
    new
    {
        @class = "form-control selectpicker",
        @Value = @Model.Description,
        onchange = "this.form.submit();"
})
```

Don't change anything in the razor view except adding the class `selectpicker`. Now initialize the plugin by setting the options in JavaScript like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true,
        showSubtext: true
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/a5r2vyu2/1/
Documentation: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/

To add data-* attributes in razor syntax replace `-` with `_` like this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>
    x.StockCode,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllStockList,
    new
    {
        @class = "form-control selectpicker",
        @Value = @Model.Description,
        onchange = "this.form.submit();",
        data_show_subtext="true",
        data_live_search="true"
})
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4844001/17447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9444805/17447).

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much for taking the time to help me. The search works perfectly. I can not get the data_show_subtext to show though, which would be the StockCode in this example

Comment: Man... you really save me the day!!  Appreciate a lot !