# Bootstrap-select attributes in Razor/.Net Core

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-select

I'm having trouble applying [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) attributes for drop down list form inputs in my .NET Core project.  In particular I would like to apply the [live search](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) attribute.

1 - I have tried the following code.  It is in a Razor page, and the '_' syntax is advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536670/add-search-functionality-on-dropdownlistfor).  This successfully applies the Bootstrap style (see screenshot) but not the additional attributes:

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Observation.BirdId, new SelectList(Model.Birds, "BirdId", "EnglishName"),
                    new {
                      @class = "form-control selectpicker",
                      data_width = "auto",
                      data_live_search = "true",
                    //data_show_subtext = "true",
           })
```

Here's the screenshot.  It shows the Bootstrap style was successfully applied, but not the live search feature.  This list will eventually contain ~600 options so a search feature is required.

[image]

2 - I have also tried applying the following code - in a blank Razor page - lifted directly from the [bootstrap-select documentation](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/).  The result is the same: it applies the Bootstrap style but not the live search functionality.  Or indeed any other attribute that I have tried:

```
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
        <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
        <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
 </select>
```

I have tried all sorts over the last couple of days.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the bottom of the problem.  I had the NuGet package installed.  I uninstalled the NuGet package.  Then I added the dependencies via the links:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
```

The various ways of installing the required dependencies are explained in the [bootstrap-select documentation](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

I had previously attempted to add the dependencies via the links.  However, I think it had conflicted with the already installed NuGet dependencies.