# How do you create html attributes with dashes when declaring html helpers in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can I, for example, create a `data-bind` attribute when I declare and `Html.TextboxFor` helper?

Doing simply:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { data-bind="something" })
```

is not legitimate because of the naming issue with a dash "-" symbol. Is there a way around this issue or is it just not possible to pass html attributes with names containing dashes?

NOTE: I tried slapping the `@` (this helps if you want to pass an atrribute that matches C# reserved words like "class") in front of the attribute but that didn't do the trick...

Comment: So underscore is converted to "-" within the html helper?

Comment: Yes. Duplicate of [Html5 data-* with asp.net mvc TextboxFor html attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844001/html5-data-with-asp-net-mvc-textboxfor-html-attributes) or [Hyphenated html attributes with asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759396/dropdownlistfor-with-a-custom-attribute-with-in-attribute-name/12759522#12759522

Comment: that's a good answer @Zabavsky but it's a bad comment ;)

Comment: your first one.  don't get me wrong, it's very helpful and it is correct.  the site philosophy though would like this question to be politely closed and redirected to one of the existing duplicates as it doesn't really add much to the canon of razor knowledge...

Comment: @dove, you are right. I removed the comment and flagged the question as duplicate.

Comment: @Zabavsky thanks, it's pedantic but it's how to keep the site quality.  I +1'd your other comment ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use underscores (`_`) for that, MVC will convert them to dashes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { data_bind = "something" })
```

Notice the `data_bind` property.