# Using hyphenated HTML attributes in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, jquery-select2

Consider the following valid razor HTML helper code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Select..." })
```

However, there are some libraries that I'm using, that uses hyphenated attributes such as this:

```
<select class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="Select...">
```

When I try to do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", data-placeholder="Select..." })
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

How can I use hyphenated attributes in razor synax?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc - refer to that for your answer

Comment: I get the same error with @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an underscore `_` - the Razor engine is smart enough to translate that to a `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc):

Use an underscore in the data attribute name, and it'll magically handle it for you, converting it to a hyphen. It knows you want a hyphen rather than an underscore as underscores aren't valid in html attributes.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name", value, new { @data_foo = "bar"}) %>
```