# razor syntax to draw bootstrap slider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap based slider in my mvc project and the razor syntax i  used on the textblock is

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Left,new { @class = "form-control", data-slider-min="0", data-slider-max="20", data-slider-step="1" })
```

And at runtime its returning error

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

So how can i set the params data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="" on HtmlTextBoxFor Razor element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyphenated html attributes with asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: You cannot declare html attributes similar to html tags inside razor syntax. As mentioned in the post provided by **Zabavsky**, you have to follow razor syntax to set html attributes.  
Your syntax should be as below:  
**`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Left,new { @class = "form-control", data_slider_min="0", data_slider_max="20", data_slider_step="1" })`**

Answer (score 3):

`data-slider-min` is being interpreted as  `data - slider - min` (i.e. `data` *minus* `slider` *minus* `min` etc)

Razor allows for hyphen/minus ("-") characters by translating underscores to hyphen/minus characters in the output of attribute names...

### e.g. use underscores:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Left,new { @class = "form-control", data_slider_min="0", data-slider-max="20", data-slider-step="1" })
```

re: the actual error reported: Are you using a strongly typed model? You must for the various "for" extension methods to work (as they generate an expression tree).

Comment: With a slight changed, this works perfectly:
`code` @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slider,new { @class = "slider", data_slider_min="1", data_slider_max="999999", data_slider_step="1", data_slider_id="blue" })

Comment: @cornelha: Please share any changes. This was typed from memory :)

Comment: I hit enter too fast lol. The basic change is to set @class="slider", the rest of the data attributes are pretty self explanatory. In my theme, the data-slider-id just denotes the color

Comment: Since I am on a roll here, the TwitterBootstrapMVC code:
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Slider).Class("slider").Data(new { slider_id = "blue", slider_max = "999999" })

Comment: @cornelha: Ah, I as just focusing on the problem reported. Thanks :)