# Using AngularJS expressions to sum two numbers in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have been searching for this for a while now but I could not find anything that solved my problem.

**Problem:**

I have been given a task to show sum of two numbers on the run, 
For Example:

`TextBox1 = 2`

`TextBox2 = 3`

`Result = 5`

Now as soon as the user changes any of the `TextBox1` or `TextBox2` value the `Result` should display their sum immediately and I have to do this using `AngularJs`.

**What have I done so far:**

I started learning `AngularJs` and I think adding two numbers is very simple as described above, My code below can do it:

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="numberA=2;numberB=3">
    Number 1: <input type="number" ng-model="numberA">
    Number 2: <input type="number" ng-model="numberB">
    <p><b>Sum:</b> {{numberA + numberB}}</p>
</div>
```

What I can not do is, do the exact same thing in ASP.NET MVC 4, I created a new Project and the above worked fine but when I started using the `Models` it does not work.

**Model:**

```
public class Check
{
    public int numberA { get; set; }
    public int numberB { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div data-ng-app="">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.numberA, new { @data-ng-model = "numberA" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.numberB, new { @data-ng-model = "numberB" })
    <p>Result: {{ numberA + numberB }} </p>
</div>
```

Now I know the above will not work because I did some research and found out that this won't work but I could not find another way of completing my task. Most of the results showed me that I will need to create simple `.html` files to make this work.

**Question:**

- Is there a simple way of doing the above? For example something that lets me integrate `AngularJs` into Razor view easily?
- If the answer to above question is no, then what will be the best way to do the task above?
- Is there no way to do this using `Razor Views` and `AngularJs` together?

Comment: Can you clarify what you found? Why would it not work, is it because you can't set `@data-ng-model`? See [Hyphenated html attributes with asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2897733/247702)

Comment: @Stijn This worked, such a small mistake :( but any ways now my expression `{{ a + b }}` is concatenating `a` and `b` not performing arithmetic sum, but If I do `{{ a * b }}` it is performing multiplication fine.

Comment: What's the rendered HTML? `public int numberA` should render as an `<input type="number"`. Compare the differences between the generated HTML from MVC and the working HTML you wrote yourself.

Comment: @Stijn It's `<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field a must be a number." data-val-required="The a field is required." id="a" name="a" ng-model="numberA" type="text" value="1" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first one is that you're not properly setting the `data-ng-model` attribute, [you must use underscores instead of hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897733/247702).

The second one is that while `EditorFor` will correctly set `type="number"` for an `int`, `TextBoxFor` will not do this, so you need to set it manually.

```
<div data-ng-app="">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.numberA, new { data_ng_model = "numberA", @type="number" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.numberB, new { data_ng_model = "numberB", @type="number" })
    <p>Result: {{ numberA + numberB }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, however Can you please tell me how can I render this expression `{{ a + b }}` into `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.b, new { ng_model = "numberB", @type = "number" })`?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi I don't understand what you mean, sorry. I assume that the result is now correctly calculated instead of doing string concatenation? What's the desired HTML?

Comment: Yes the result is calculated and it's working fine, but for example I want to set the result to a `TextBox` rendered using `Html Helper function`...

Comment: Ok Its working now, I meant this:
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.b, new { ng_value = "numberA + numberB" })`