# How to set data-display in razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a basic password strength indicator.

```
<input type="password" id="myElement1" size="40" class="left" data-display="myDisplayElement1" />
<div class="left" id="myDisplayElement1"></div>
```

I have the `JS Script` which takes care of all the logic. And the `data-display div` shows the message whether the password is weak or strong. But I want to convert the above code into Razor. Below is what I have till now.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "myElement1" } })
        <div class="left" id="myDisplayElement1"></div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Question: Everything is working fine but I am not able to put data-display attribute in razor. Where do I need to place it. But as the data-display is not set, I am not able to display the user its password strength as the div.

I want to be able to do something like below

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "myElement1" , data-display = "myDisplayElement1"} })
```

But `data-display` gives me error.

**Error**

Cannot resolve symbol `data` the error comes at the place where I have added `data-display`.

Comment: Please read [ask], share your research and mention the exact error next time.

Comment: I have added the error message. And I have put the code snippet too. if you are satisfied please take out the negative vote. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyphenation is not valid within an anonymous object. However, knowing that it would be necessary at times to add attributes with hyphenation, the Razor helpers will auto replace underscores with hyphens in attribute names. As a result, you can accomplish what you need by using `data_display` rather than `data-display`.

Comment: Which is addressed in the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc), one of many questions dealing with this subject. Are you sure it warrants yet another version of an answer that exists many times on the site already? :)

Comment: @Chris: Thank you so so much for the answer. CodeCaster: Thanks for guiding me on how to ask question correctly.