# C# HtmlHelpers How to Escape / Preserve underscores in attribute names

Tags: c#, razor-2

when using HtmlHelpers in Razor code, like this:

```
new { data-something_something = "value" }
```

The underscores are converted "magically" to hyphens.  But what if I need my attributes to contain underscores AND hyphens?  How can I escape or otherwise preserve the underscore?

Comment: ["It knows you want a hyphen rather than an underscore as underscores aren't valid in html attribute names."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12091886/11683)

Comment: Does even underscores valid in html attribute names?

Comment: @RandikaRatnayake Underscores are only valid in data attributes, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an `IDictinoary<string, string>` instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prop, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "data-something_something", "value" } })
```

Please note that attribute names like `some_attr` is considered invalid HTML, but in your case `data-*` attributes *[can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)* indeed contain underscores.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)