# How to add attributes with hyphen and colon to Html Helper methods in razor? (vuejs syntax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add **v-on:click** or **@click** in like following html helper method:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItnScanCaseCode, new { @id="txtid",@click = "onchangeevent();" })
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary` for `htmlAttributes` like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItnScanCaseCode, htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "v-on:click", "onchangeevent()" },
    { "id", "txtid" }
})
```

Answer (score -3):

You just have to use an underscore rather than a - razor will replace it with a hyphen. its a simple as that!!!

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItnScanCaseCode, new { @id="txtid",v_on:click = "onchangeevent();" })
```

Comment: @AnikSaha Then your doing it wrong 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc  

https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc/example/7318/adding-a-custom-attribute-with----hyphen--in-name

Comment: There is difference between hyphen and colon  .