# How to add checked attribute of checkbox in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a checkbox and when I press it, I need to add `checked` attribute to cshtml.

When I deselect the checkbox, I need to remove this attribute. How can I do it?

Now, when I press it, nothing is happens. I need to change the value of `Checked` variable somehow.

View model:

```
public class ListProductVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

`.cshtml` page:

```
    <div class="compare-checkbox form-checkbox">
        <input name="compare-@Model.Id" class="js-favorite-checkbox" type="checkbox" @(Model.Checked ? "checked" : "") data-product-id="@Model.Id">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [CheckBoxFor](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-checkbox-checkboxfor) HTML helper:

```
@model ListProductVM

<div class="compare-checkbox form-checkbox">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checked, new { @class="js-favorite-checkbox", @data_product_id="@Model.Id" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Checked)
</div>
```

Note that `data_product_id` will be rendered as `data-product-id` in the html file: [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897733/hyphenated-html-attributes-with-asp-net-mvc)

---

Here is a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OWT6aY)

Comment: Whith this code I don't see the checkbox and attribute when I press on the checkbox

Comment: the checked attribute doesn't seem to be added in your solution.

Comment: @HusainAlhamali: What do you mean it does not work!? I have linked a working demo in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery/javascript for this. Add this to your page

```
 <script>

    $('.js-favorite-checkbox').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            this.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else
        {
            this.removeAttribute("checked"); 
        }
    });

 </script>
```