# Extract custom parameter

Tags: javascript

Do anyone has similar experience? I would like to get the custom parameter when I click on the image rather than only the id. I got **undefined** for second alert(this.ads), how can I get the number 2 from this parameter?

HTML

```
<section id="home" data-role="page">
    <article data-role="content">
        <div id="home-content">Home Content here <a href="#tab-3" data-transition="slide">Goto Tab-3</a>
        <div id="tab-3-list">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <img id="c02" ads="2" class="coupon_list" src="/images/coupon/c02.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ui-grid-a -->
        </div>
        <!-- /tab-3-list -->
        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- content -->
</section>
<!-- home -->
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tab-3-list img.coupon_list").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(this.id);
        alert(this.ads);
    });

});
```

Comment: [Is it OK to add your own attributes to HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305734/is-it-ok-to-add-your-own-attributes-to-html-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom attributes - Yea or nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by using,

```
alert($(this).attr('ads'));
```

It would provide you with the custom attribute's value.

### EDIT: Adding Custom Attribute for JavaScript's Use

If you want to add a custom attribute just to use it for your own good, like getting more data details in the HTML elements for further usage by the JavaScript.

You can use `data-` attribute. It would be easy and simple. Here is an example for that

```
<img data-abs="2" src="/images/coupon/c02.png" alt="coupon photo" />
```

Now, you can use `.data()` method to get out the values, http://api.jquery.com/data/ (jQuery API for data method).

Here is how you can use it

```
$('img').data('abs'); // output would be 2
```

Comment: using $(this).data('ads') is more directly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

"ads" is an attribute of the img-tag, so you can get its value with

```
alert($(this).attr("ads"));
```

[jQuery .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ads` with `data-ads` which is correct according to HTML5.

Then use either native javascript:

```
this.getAttribute('data-ads');
```

or jQuery:

```
$(this).data('ads');
//or
$(this).attr('data-ads');
```