# jquery-ui dialog: set dialog properties in HTML/CSS?

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

This is a trivial question, but: do you know if it is possible to define the properties of a Jquery-UI dialog in the HTML/CSS of the corresponding DIV? [The docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) just show how to do it in Javascript.

Thanks for any help

l

Comment: What kind of properties are you referring to?

Comment: Steven, all those that control the aspect and behavior of the dialog: eg, autoOpen, width, height, <a href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#options">etc</a>.

Comment: sorry, didn't know comment boxes don't like html : ) The link is http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#options%22%3Eetc%3C/a%3E

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
You can define custom properties for your HTML tag like `<div dialogwidth="400"></div>`
This will work but this won't be valid.
In HTML5 you can create custom attributes (more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag)).

You can also create invisible tag and keep settings inside it:

```
<div id="dialog">
    Dialog text.
    <div style="display: none;" class="dialog-width">400</div>
</div>
<script>
alert("Dialog width is " + $("#dialog") + "px");
</script>
```

But this solution is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Things like max-height/width, display and other default CSS properties, can be controlled in CSS.
But other jQuery specific properties, can only be set in you javascript file.