# Telling Zope/Chameleon to not parse a section?

Tags: python, html, pyramid, zope, chameleon

I have a Pyramid app that uses Chameleon. I need to declare some attributes in my DOCTYPE, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE public html .........
[
    <!ATTLIST tag attributes CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

When I add this to my template, id doesn't get rendered properly and my browser draws "]>".
When I remove the ATTLIST and only do `<!DOCTYPE public html .........>`, everything works.

How can I tell Chameleon to not parse the ATTLIST section and copy it as is?

Answer (score 2):

That has absolutely nothing to do with Chameleon. If I paste that code into a file and open it in my browser, I see `]>` as well.

Edit: I figured it out. Rename the file to `.xhtml` and it will work (at least for me).

If you're receiving it over the network, having the `content-type` set to `application/xhtml+xml` would work the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag supposedly, this should be possible.. is it possible to add to an existing doctype? I don't want to create a custom one all together..

Comment: thanks! the correct content type that solved the problem is "application/xhtml+xml" (not "text/html")