# Attribute and Variable (Simple)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a VARIABLE as a ATTRIBUTE value...

I have :

```
var text = "Hello!";
```

and the HTML is :

`<li class="pro" id="text">` ---> (I want the attribute ID to equals the TEXT variable)

How can I make this work?

Thank you

---

EDIT

I will be more specific in my question.

Here's what I really have :

```
<li class="product" name="RD-101" price="18"  minimum="4" gap="4"> 
                         <a class="product-image fancybox" href="images/product_big.jpg" title="Picture 4">
                             <img src="images/product_2.png" alt="Preview"/>
                             <div class="text-overlay">
                              <p class="product-heading">Description</p>
                               Enseignes résidentielles imprimées sur 2 panneaux 4 mm 36” x 24” collés dos à dos.
                             </div>
                         </a>
                         <p class="product-heading">RD-101 (Simple)</p>
                         <a href="#" id="test" class="product-buy">Ajouter au panier</a>
                         <p class="product-meta">Double de pareterre 32x24</p>
                         <div class="product-price">18<span class="product-currency">$</span></div>

                    </li>
```

As you can see I use custom attributes that are set in my Javascript code.
I want to know how to set (for instance)...the PRICE attribute to a VARIABLE VALUE instead of the number "18" like it is right now in what I pasted up there.

I was thinking of something like -->

```
<li class="product" name="RD-101" price="MY_VARIABLE_HERE"  minimum="4" gap="4">
```

Comment: `li` elements do not have a `name` attribute. use `data-name` if you want to store custom data.

Comment: Ok. But let's say the attribute is "id"...How can I make it equals the TEXT variable value? That's what I need to know

Comment: @user1388136 Since your update, I'm now confused. Are you saying you want the ID of this particular <LI> object to be the same as the content of the "text" variable?  So in your example, the desired outcome is <li class="pro" id="Hello!">?  It seems a bit of a strange request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("li.pro").attr('id', text);` with jQuery

Remember attribute `name` is not valid for a `<li>`

EDIT :

With no jQuery, this code add a `price` (not valid) attribute to all `li` elements

```
<ul id="my_ul_id">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

-

```
var text = 'Hello';
var arr_li = document.getElementById("my_ul_id").getElementsByTagName("li"); 
for(var i=0 ; i<arr_li.length ; i++)
{
  arr_li[i].setAttribute('price', text);
}
```

Last thing, we said `price` wasn't a valid attribute.
If you want your HTML doc to be valid, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag)

Comment: Thank you. So there's no HTML/Javascript way to do this? I cannot just type ---> id="MYVARIABLE" ?

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library, which will simplify your life, your can do it without it too.

Comment: Ok. So I cannot just write --> <li id="MY VARIABLE"> ? Or something like that?

Comment: Mmmh... depends of what you're doing. Why are you searching to change an id ?

Comment: Well it's not an ID I'm trying to change. I'm using custom attributes, so the real attribute I want to change is called PRICE. so <li price="MYVARIABLE">...that's what I wanted it to look like

Comment: Ok, then will you change a specific `<li>` or severals ? If they've got distincts `id`, it's easy to do.

Comment: That's for severals <li>. They do not have iD for now, but I guess I could add them. How would it look like?

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look. More, to be sure you won't modify others `li` elements, I suggest you to add an id on you `ul` and use this id to identify clearly your list : `var arr_li = document.getElementById("my_ul_id").getElementsByTagName("li");`

Comment: Ok. I edited my first post, maybe it will help you understand what I'm looking for?

Comment: Ok, then my last update is good for you. Your JS code will be executed after the document load, so use `getElementById`, `getElementByClass` and/or `getElementByTagName` to find the `li` you're searching for, and then use `setAttribute` as specified.

Comment: So the html code will look like this? : <li class="product" name="RD-101" price=""  minimum="4" gap="4">...Do I have to type anything in the PRICE attribute? Or can I leave it blank, since I will change the value with the code anyways?

Comment: Yes, the HTML code will looks like this, and yes you can leave it blank.

Comment: I was just finishing an example (http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/Fwzek/), you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

As you've specified "javascript" rather than "jquery", you could do something along the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = "Hello!";
document.getElementById("liItem").setAttribute("id",text);
</script>

<ul>
  <li class="pro" id="liItem">
</ul>
```

**Updated** to reflect change of attribute from "name" to "id"

Comment: Ok. I edited my first post, maybe it will help you understand what I'm looking for?

Comment: Looks like you've got it sorted with samsamX, well done to you both. For future reference, say what you're after straight off... there's no point confusing people by asking for something different (and in this case something that didn't make sense)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the JQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
var theName = 'yourMom';
$('li.pro').attr('name', theName);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J798a/2/

Comment: Ok. I edited my first post, maybe it will help you understand what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.pro").attr('name', text);
```

you can use any name for attribute, you like

Answer (score 1):

Javascript would set it with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = "Hello!";
    document.getElementById("changeMe").setAttribute("id",text);
</script>

<ul>
   <li id="changeMe">
</ul>
```

setAttribute sets the provided attribute (first argument) to the value of the second arguement... so element.setAttribute("name", "john smith") would set the name to "john smith" and element.setAttribute("class", "math") would set the class attribute to "math".

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with javascript templating libraries.

Some examples:

- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)/[CanJS](http://canjs.us/)
- [a ton of others](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/)

With JavascriptMVC, for example, an ejs file containing the following line (where text is actually a JS variable) will be transformed to html:

```
<li class="pro" id="<%= text %>">
```

You may read on this here:
http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.View

Welcome to the Fantastic Infinite Javascript Framework/libraries world :)!!

Comment: Looking good. So that means the <%= text %> is in fact the TEXT variable? but as the ID, right?