# how remove one of div list

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code.

```
<div id="list"> <div class="a">1</div><div class="b">1</div></div>
<div id="list"> <div class="a">2</div><div class="b">2</div></div>
<div id="list"> <div class="a">3</div><div class="b">3</div></div>
<div id="list"> <div class="a">4</div><div class="b">4</div></div>
```

I need to delete

```
<div id="list"> <div class="a">3</div><div class="b">3</div></div>

I tried $('#list[2]').remove() but it doesn't work. Help me, please.
```

Comment: Comment out the third line? :]

Comment: You have multiple `div`s with the same `id`.  That's invalid HTML, `id`s must be unique within a document.

Comment: Use classes for things like this.  It's what they're for.

Comment: ID's are unique, but `$('div[id="list"]').eq(2).remove()` should still work.

Comment: problem one, You cannot have more that one element with the same id

Answer (score 2):

Better not to use the same ids, that's going to mess-up your document as IDs are UNIQUE, use Class instead:

```
<div class="list"> <div class="a">1</div><div class="b">1</div></div>
<div class="list"> <div class="a">2</div><div class="b">2</div></div>
<div class="list"> <div class="a">3</div><div class="b">3</div></div>
<div class="list"> <div class="a">4</div><div class="b">4</div></div>
```

Access it thru:

```
$('div[class="list"]').eq(2).remove();
```

Or:

```
$('.list').eq(2).remove();
```

You see `eq(2)` because the elements start getting counted from `0`, so 2 is your third element with a `list` class.

Comment: Your first example won't work. Also, don't make up your own attributes. Prefix them with `data-`.

Comment: @Blender: right, good point, I fixed it.

Comment: maybe I'm a pedant, but why not `$('div.list').eq(1).remove();`?

Comment: @Blender, Could you elaborate on 'making up your own attributes'?

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly what's the difference btwn $('div.list') and $('.list')? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk - You should **not** arbitrarily create your own custom attributes for html tags.  If you need to add custom data to an element, you should use a custom attribute prefixed by `data-`.  More reading [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/).

Comment: In the given example? little. I wrote that before you had added `$('.list').eq(1).remove();`, which pretty much covers what I was suggesting. It would only make a difference if he had other tags (not divs) that used the list class

Comment: @jahroy, The article is about HTML5, does the same go for HTML?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk - Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1735230/778118) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992115/778118).  I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735268/778118) (along with the comment below) pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `id="list"` to `class="list"` and try

```
$(".list:contains('3')").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple iterations of an `id` will cause problems on your page. Change them to the `class` attribute and manipulate at will!

http://jsfiddle.net/q5Wuh/

Feel free to add a click event to it as well

http://jsfiddle.net/qcGHR/

Answer (score 0):

If you will use eq(2) it will remove the div at index 2 and remember index is 0 zero based.

For generic answer try below code.

```
$('.a:contains(3)').parent().remove()
```

Whatever you need to search specify as argument in contains. Here we are supposed to search '3' so we passing it as 3.

**Note: Also always remember that id should in unique in DOM. It's the first and foremost rule.**

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/dfHeP/)