# add attribute to a <th> without id or class

Tags: jquery

i want to add an attribute to a table header without id or class. all it has is field. my code here does not work. i appreciate any help

```
$(th[field = "item_group_ID"]).attr('hidden', 'true');
```

or is there any other way i can do this? heres the table

```
<table id="dg" title="jaiko pogi " class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:980px;height:370px;"
        url="show_biochem.php"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="false" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" height="auto";>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th field="item_group_ID" width="8">ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

solved it. i read the documentation and turns out there is a function for this. anyway thanks for the help

```
$('#dg').datagrid('hideColumn','item_group_ID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect. It should be a string:

```
$('th[field="item_group_ID"]').attr('hidden', 'true');
```

Also, are you trying to hide the element? If so, adding an attribute called "hidden" won't do it.. try this instead:

```
$('th[field="item_group_ID"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes:

```
$("th[field='item_group_ID']").attr('hidden', 'true');
```

If you are trying to hide the selected element use `.hide()` function, instead.

Comment: thanks. the function now executes but still doesnt do anything. what am i missing here?

Comment: What are you trying yo do? If you want to hide the element, just use `.hide()` jQuery function.

Comment: tried it, still wouldnt hide. http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php this is the one im using.

Comment: @raymond can you create please a JSFIDDLE with your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an attribute that is not part of the official HTML syntax (i.e. `field`), you can use attributes named `data-*` (i.e. `data-field`). So:

```
<th data-field="item_group_ID" width="8">ID</th>
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735268/1165203