# How to get data from DIV in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, date

I have collection of `div` in my Application. One of functionality I want to implement is Date Filter. It looks like this:

```
var iExamDate = new Date(aData[9]);
var startDate = new Date($('#start-datepicker-min').val());
var endDate = new Date($('#end-datepicker-max').val());
iExamDateMatch = (startDate <= iExamDate && endDate >= iExamDate);
return iExamDateMatch;
```

From Firefox Debugger:

```
aData[9] = <div id="Exmdt_1" shortdate="11/3/2011" longdate="12:00:00" am="">11/3/2011</div>
```

When I checked iExamDate I saw `NaN` of course, because I've tried to create `new Date` from whole `div`

How should I create iExamdate in order to get Date correct.
Any help, please.
Thanks

Comment: As an aside, based on the HTML you are showing it is invalid because of the attributes you are adding. If you are targeting HTML5 you should be pre-pending those with 'data-'. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735268/603520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or 
    $(aData[9]).attr("shortdate")

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.text()` function to get the text within the `<div>`. However, I see you are also storing the date in an attribute, so you could use the `getAttribute()` function, also. Keep in mind, these must be used with jQuery, so it will depend on what `aData[9]` is. Is it a string containing the HTML of the div? Or is it the jQuery object for the div itself?

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the second answer, because that's exactly what I need, but your answer more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAttribute()` method to achieve this.

```
aData[9].getAttribute('shortdate');
```

Or if you want to get value from inside of div use `innerHTML`

```
aData[9].innerHTML;
```