# Is the any restriction in using currently present Image property?

Tags: c#

I want to write some property item to image. Though I could not do it. But I can edit any currently added property. So I want to know is there are any property item I can use for my purpose? Here are some Id I am getting:

```
Id:271
type 2

Id:272
type:2

Id:274
type:3

Id:282
type:5

Id:283
type:5

Id:296
type:3

Id:306
type:2
....
```

etc.

My question is can I use any of the currently present property?

Comment: Do you want to give image a Id? Why not create a custom image class which wraps a image and necessary properties?

Comment: I want to add 2 time stamp and photographer name to image metadata. For this purpose I want to use any of the currently added image PropertyItem. Is there any problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds simple i think

```
<img id="myimage" data-id="data you want to pass"/>
```

if you want to add attribute from c# then

```
ddLedger.Attributes.Add('data-id','yourvalue');
```

So you want to access this property at backend c# then

```
string aa=myimage.attributes("data-id");
```

in string aa you will get your data....

and in jquery

```
$('#myimage').attr('data-id');
```

Now if you want to add it at run time then like this

```
$('#myimage').attr('data-id','your id added');
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/raqasuso/1/)

Check this url for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735239/2630817

I hope this will help you....:)

Comment: The revision history for the question shows that it might be about WinForms, not asp.net.

Comment: I know but he added it later so what can i do now? @gunr2171

Comment: Just leave it. It's a good answer to a vague question. You're not getting any downvotes, so no worries.