# What is the significance of cmdValue in the input tag?

Tags: html, tags

What is the significance of `cmdValue` in the input tag in the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Bold" cmdValue="bold">
```

This is from `<div id="actions">` on a [website](https://www.branah.com/text-to-image).

I looked up the input tag on several HTML reference sites and searched for `cmdValue` in conjunction with the input tag, but could find no data.

Comment: Could be just a custom attribute they use for who knows what. It's not a standard attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a formal HTML attribute for any known tag.

That is certainly a customized attribute added by the developers of that website.

I prefer to forward you to read the answers of  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag).

Answer (score 0):

The significance is whatever the CSS or JavaScript code for the page assigns to it. You would need to analyze the page in detail to find this out.

As such, the nonstandard has no effect beyond getting inserted into the DOM as an attribute.