# how can I fix this error "There is no attribute colorcode, selected or tabindex"

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
colorthumbs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var colorcode = this.getAttribute('colorcode');
    var thumbimg = document.getElementById('productthumbs').getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < thumbimg.length; i++) {
```

```html
 <div id="colorpanel" style="border-bottom:1px solid lightgray;">
     <p><b>Select Color</b></p>
     <div class='productthumbs'>
         <img class="thumbimg" src="Images/p1s1c1.jpeg"  alt="color1" colorcode="1" selected="selected" style="border-color:brown;"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

This has to be xhtml strict 1.0 only nothing else. been working on a ton of errors and now down to these last three.

Line 83, Column 92: there is no attribute "colorcode"
Line 83, Column 105: there is no attribute "selected"
Line 117, Column 94: there is no attribute "tabIndex"

Comment: Way too much code, limit code to the actual problem (ie code around the 3 lines that your error messages reference)

Comment: ok i did that. updated the code.

Comment: Well, it's pretty easy... in xhtml strict 1.0, the `<img>` tag does not have an attribute `colorcode` (and I'm not aware that it does in any other doctype), therefor adding it is not allowed/gives an error

Comment: ah ... how would this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute in HTML called "colorcode", where did you get colorcode="1"? The selected attribute is not for the img tag, it is meant for a drop down menu. Remove both of these from your img tag.

I see nothing in your code about tabindex but I suspect it is because you capitalized the "I" in index. XHTML is case sensitive, so element and attribute names are generally lowercase.

Fix all three of these and your code should work.

Comment: var existingsrc = thumbimg[i].getAttribute('src');
            var arr = existingsrc.split('/');
            var ext = arr[1].substr(6,arr[1].length);
            var updated = arr[1].substring(0,5) + colorcode + ext;
            var src = arr[0] + '/' + updated;
            thumbimg[i].setAttribute('src',src);
          }

Comment: you were right about the tabindex. but once i remove the colorcode and selected my page doesnt function right

Comment: How doesn't it function correctly? What if you just remove one of them?

Comment: still not functioning i tried deleting one of the attributes

Comment: What is it not doing that you are expecting it to do?

Comment: when i click on pictures they disappear. and u can see white with a border and the alt name. mouse over effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76312/discussion-between-wilfredo-turner-and-kojow7).

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2yljtic.png . for selecting the color of shirt if there was 2 color options. <img class="thumbimg" src="Images/p2s1c2.jpeg"  alt="color2" colorcode="2"/>

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use attributes in HTML that do not exist.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

If you would like to add custom attributes to your code, maybe try this: [Can I add custom attribute to HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag)