# Get HTML tag from Attribute having value "xyz"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a html tag as below (no `id` or `class` defined):
`<a href="#" letter="xyz">All</a>`
i need to *get the **tag** having attribute value='xyz'*
i was successful in finding the attribute by:
`var html_tag = $("a").find('[letter="xyz"]');`
but it returns an object.
i need to get html tag so that i can use it as:
`$(html_tag).css('color','#FFFFFF');`
Or suggest me any other solution if this is not possible.

Comment: Are you saying that _any_ element might have that attribute, so in this instance the result of `html_tag` should just be `a`, so you can then select _all_ `<a>` tags?

Comment: Nopes.. whats i was trying to achieve was answered by Satpal correctly :)
i was having list of `<a>` having "unique" attribute (letter) value. So i needed to find that specific tag that contains attribute having value equal to "xyz"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("a").find('[letter="xyz"]')` will find descendants of anchor with attribute value `letter="xyz"`

You need to use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with anchor tag

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

*Use*

```
$('a[letter="xyz"]').css('color','#FFFFFF');
```

You could also use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$("a").filter('[letter="xyz"]').css('color','#FFFFFF');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to find element in anchor element that have letter attr equal to xyz. which do not exists. Using `.filter()` instead of `.find()` would solve the problem.

However you can simply use:

```
var html_tag = $('a[letter="xyz"]');
```

Note: you should use `.data-*` attributes(added in HTML5) for adding custom attributes as adding your own attributes can break elements validation and make html invalid (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735239/1719752).

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
var anchorTag = $('a[letter="xyz"]');
```