# jQuery hide elements if matched to list regardless of order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide span elements if they match words in a wordList.

HTML:

```
<span class="wordBank_Words">
     <span word="hello"></span>
     <span word="you"></span>
     <span word="hi"></span>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
wordList = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];

$('.wordBank_Words span').each(function (index, val) {
    if ($(this).attr('word').match(wordList)) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

So, if done correctly, it should hide 'hello' and 'you', but not 'hi'

If I do `match('hello')`, this correctly hides 'hello' span from the HTML element list.

But I need to loop through each span element in `wordBank_Words`, and compare them against each word in the wordList, and only hide if there is a match. They need to be compared regardless of order.

How can this be done?

Comment: look at `Array.indexOf()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need of looping over all the elements.

You can create an [**attribute-value**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector from array by joining them to form the correct selector.

```
'[word="' + wordList.join('"], [word="') + '"]'
```

will create a selector as

```
[word="hello"], [word="how"], [word="are"], [word="you"]
```

which then can be passed to jQuery.

**Demo**

```js
var wordList = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];

var selector = '[word="' + wordList.join('"], [word="') + '"]';

$('.wordBank_Words').find(selector).hide();
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wordBank_Words">
  <span word="hello">Hello</span>
  <span word="you">You</span>
  <span word="hi">Hi</span>
  <span word="not">Not Found</span>
</span>
```

---

You can also use `attr`/`prop` methods as follow

```js
var wordList = ["hello", "how", "are", "you"], re = wordList.join("|");

$(".wordBank_Words span").attr('word', function(index, val) {
  if (wordList.indexOf(val) > -1)
    $(this).hide();
  return val;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span class="wordBank_Words">
  <span word="hello">hello</span>
  <span word="you">you</span>
  <span word="hi">hi</span>
</span>
```

Comment: _"Sidenote: word is not a valid attribute"_ ? At `html5` document ? Why would attribute not be valid ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, updated. Also added the link to the post. You can find `You can add custom attributes to your elements at will. But that will make your document invalid` in the answers.

Comment: _"3.2.3.1 Attributes Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such attributes."_ http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attribute

Comment: @guest271314 As you can see in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735783/2025923 the doctype has to change

Comment: `html5` does not have a `dtd`

Comment: Yes "invalid" , though `Error: Attribute word not allowed on element span at this point.` could be ignored ; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag/1735783#comment1615649_1735268

Comment: @guest271314 That's what I was trying to say, that the page is invalid, to  make it valid use `data-*` attributes

Answer (score 2):

I would change the word-attributes to html 5 valid data-attributes:

```
<span class="wordBank_Words">
     <span data-word="hello"></span>
     <span data-word="you"></span>
     <span data-word="hi"></span>
</span>
```

Then loop through the spans and hide the ones on the list:

```
$(function () {
    var wordList = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
    $(".wordBank_Words span").each(function () {
        if (wordList.indexOf($(this).data("word")) > -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.indexOf() to check whether the word exists in the array like

```js
var wordList = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];

$('.wordBank_Words span').each(function(index, val) {
  $(this).toggle(wordList.indexOf($(this).attr('word')) == -1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wordBank_Words">
  <span word="hello"></span>
  <span word="you"></span>
  <span word="hi"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `|` to `RegExp` using `.join()`, `!== null` after `.match()` to condition

```js
var wordList = ["hello", "how", "are", "you"], re = wordList.join("|");

$(".wordBank_Words span").each(function(index, val) {
  if ( $(this).attr('word').match(re) !== null ) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span class="wordBank_Words">
  <span word="hello">hello</span>
  <span word="you">you</span>
  <span word="hi">hi</span>
</span>
```