# Can we use own attributes in html elements for store values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on HTML and JavaScript. I need to store some values in HTML and use that some for other purpose for other languages like JAVA (HTML parsing).

Can I use own attributes like  `column='helloworld`'? Is it valid in HTML?

I also see `"data-"`, but I don't know what happened if I do not use `"data-"`.

Does that give any error ?

Please elaborate someone, I have no expertise in HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="1" class="text-clone" name="default">
<select id="Name" class="dropdown-clone" name="Name">
  <option value="">Name</option>
  <option value="MyName">myName</option>
</select>

$('#'+id).find("input[type=text]").attr("column",$("#Name").val());
```

Name value is any string like "myName".

after this when I see on my browser by using inspect element , column="myName" . So I am confused why we can not do this which I did , that is wrong or correct . safe or not ?

Comment: How about using cookies? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code and in this case also tell us why you cannot use the perfectly useful data attributes

Comment: I would have used `data-myAttribute=something`

Comment: I used simple column='myName' , there have not error , that is working then why we can't use it . Sorry if I did wrong .

Comment: You did not do wrong. Add examples of your HTML to your question and tell us exactly where you are planning to use it

Comment: @mplungjan : I added code  html and a single method of jquery .

Comment: @mplungjan : please give any suggestion or answer , I am waiting ......

Comment: `.attr("column",$("#Name").val())` or `.data("column",$("#Name").val())` would work the same

Comment: @mplungjan: So , that means I am doing correct ?

Comment: I would not personally use custom attributes but they are allowed. See Anduit's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say using custom attributes is okey and valid as soon as many frameworks like Angular use it as well. Your can find some information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag)

Should you use it? Hard to say. For many situations cookies is much easier and cleaner option as @mtb say in comment.

About data attribute you mentioned in your question:

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be
>   associated with a particular element but need not have any defined
>   meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on
>   standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as
>   non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or setUserData.

For more information about it check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)