# HTML attribute spsourceindex

Tags: html

In legacy code, I encountered an unknown attribute ***spsourceindex***, what is it used for?
Example

```
<nav class="size-options">
    <a href="#" class="any-class" spsourceindex="25">One</a>
    <a href="#" class="any-class" spsourceindex="30">Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="any-class" spsourceindex="31">Three</a>
    <a href="#" class="any-class" spsourceindex="32">Four</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can have custom attributes in html, and use them in your JavaScript code

Comment: You can make some search on internet for this ;-)

Comment: igor milla, thank you. The search finds the word but does not explain what it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag