# How to get attribut value id_user use post Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get the `id_user` data based on the desired row table using `onclick jquery`, so the already obtained `id_user` data can be passed to the controller and direct the page to `edit_user`.

How do I get the `id_user` data with `onclick` using the jquery function? I tried it but what I got **'undefined'**.

Sorry for my bad English.

**This is my function**

```
function edit(){
    var id_user = $(this).attr("id_user");
    alert(id_user);


    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url : "<?php echo BASE_URL ?>app.php/usermanagement/edit_user",
        data :{id_user:id_user},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data)
            console.log(data)
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert(err)
        }
    });
}
```

**This my `a` tag**

```
  <a onclick="edit()" id_user="<? echo $row ['idx']; ?>" href="#" >Edit</a>
```

This is my code for edit_user form

```
<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend> Edit User Management </legend>
    <table border="0" width="700" id="usermanagement">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="160"><strong>Company</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td width="193" colspan="2" class="company"><span class ="id_company"><?php echo Session::get('pyrCode'); ?></span> <?php echo $data_from_ctr['account']['desc']['desc'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Username</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_user']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="existing_username" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_user']; ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Email</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['email']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Status User</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="radio" name="status_active" value="1" <?php if ($data_from_ctr['user']['active'] == 1) { ?>  checked="" <? } ?> id="aktif"/>
                    &nbsp;Active
            <input type="radio" name="status_active" value="0" <?php if ($data_from_ctr['user']['active'] == 0) {  ?> checked="" <? } ?> id="nonaktif" />
                    &nbsp;Non Active
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Status User</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
           <input type="radio" name="status_active" value="<?php //echo $data_from_ctr['user']['active']; ?>"  checked="" id="aktif"/>
                    &nbsp;Active
            <input type="radio" name="status_active" value="<?php //echo $data_from_ctr['user']['active'];?>" id="nonaktif" />
                    &nbsp;Non Active
            </td>
            </tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_fullName']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_noHP']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Access Control</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="access" name="access">
                <option <?php if ($data_from_ctr['user']['group_user'] == 'user'){ ?> selected="" <? } ?> value="user">User </option>
                <option <?php if ($data_from_ctr['user']['group_user'] == 'admin_bank'){ ?> selected="" <? } ?> value="admin_bank">Admin Bank</option>
                <option <?php if ($data_from_ctr['user']['group_user'] == 'admin_client'){ ?> selected="" <? } ?> value="admin_client">Admin Client</option>
            </select>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  <?php if ($data_from_ctr['user']['group_user'] != 'user'){ ?> style= "display: none" <? }  ?> class="odd level">
            <td width="150"><strong>Level</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="level" name="level">
                <option <?php if($data_from_ctr['user']['_status'] == '01'){ ?> selected="" <? } ?> value="01">Inputer</option>
                <option <?php if($data_from_ctr['user']['_status'] == '02'){ ?> selected="" <? } ?> value="02">Verificator</option>
                <option <?php if($data_from_ctr['user']['_status'] == '03'){  ?> selected="" <? }?> value="03">Authorize 1</option>
                <option <?php if($data_from_ctr['user']['_status'] == '04'){ ?>  selected="" <? } ?> value="04">Authorize 2</option>
                <option <?php if($data_from_ctr['user']['_status'] == '05'){ ?> selected="" <? } ?> value="05">COPS</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none" class="limit">
            <td width="150"><strong>Limit Transaction</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="limit" id="limit value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['limit']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Account Access</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="acctAccessed" name="acctAccessed[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" data-placeholder="Select account">
            <?php foreach ($data_from_ctr['account']['account'] as $data) :?>    
            <option <?php if($data['selected'] == "1"){ ?> selected="" <? } ?>value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['_giro_OB']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <input id="chkall" type="checkbox" >Select All</input>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="btnsubmitdis" type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

This is my Controller

```
public function edit(){

        Template::setTitle('Edit User Management');

        $id_user =(int)Request::post('id_user');

        //$id_user = (int)$_POST['id_user'];

        echo $id_user; die;

        //$id_user = (int)Session::get('idx');

        $result = $this->getUserbyId($id_user);      

        $dataresult = json_decode($result, true);
        if($dataresult === NULL) {
            echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\No Have Data\");";
            echo "javascript:history.back();</script>";
            return false;
        }
        $data = $dataresult;
        return $data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do this way:

```
<a onclick="edit(<? echo $row ['idx']; ?>)" 
   id_user="<? echo $row ['idx']; ?>" href="#" >Edit</a>
 // if it gets the id then pass it to the calling function here.
```

then in the function:

```
function edit(idUser){ // get the id here
    var id_user = idUser; // and process it here.
    alert(id_user);
    ...
```

or you can pass `this` to the calling function:

```
onclick="edit(this)"
```

and inside your edit function:

```
function edit(currEl){ // get the this ref here
    var id_user = $(currEl).attr('id_user'); // and extract the attr here.
    alert(id_user);
    ...
```

Comment: thanks @Jai this is work, I wanna asking again, How can I redirect page to edit_user and bring data id_user after I get data id_user?

Comment: @TinaMaya This something can't be answered in this thread. you have to ask a separate question for this as this seems too much to answer here. Yet you can make a get request and send the id in the url to get it. This is one way of doing other than this you can use sessionStorage for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some method to do it :

1) Change `id_user` in your `a` tag by `data-id-user` and try `var id_user = $(this).data("id-user");`, remove the `onclick` event on your html tag and add an id so you can do the same in jQuery :

```js
$("#edit_id_user").on("click", function() {
     console.log($(this).data('id-user'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="edit_id_user" data-id-user="test" href="#" >Edit</a>
```

2) Now if you want to keep your edit function, just add a `this` inside so you can get the current element inside your function:

```js
function edit(elt) {
    console.log($(elt).data('id-user'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="edit(this)" data-id-user="test" href="#" >Edit</a>
```

3) Look `Jai` answer : just add the id as param in your function so you get it easily

Here is an other question about adding custom attribute to HTML tag that might be interesting for you : [Can I add a custom attribute to an HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag)

Comment: it's same undefined @Mickaël Leger

Comment: I edited my qestion, need to add a `this` reference as param in yoru edit function and I give you an other way to do it without the onclick event inside your html tag. But you can't add custom tag as `id_user` inside html tag (look the link I add in my question), you need to use `data-***`. Tell me if all is ok !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery. I would recommend to use jquery onclick method rather than javascript native method.

So your html should look like this

```
<a data-id-user="<? echo $row ['idx']; ?>" href="#" class="banner_content">Edit</a>
```

Below is the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.banner_content').click(function() {
    var id_user = $(this).data('id-user');
    alert(id_user);
    //your ajax call goes here
  });
});
```

for custom attribute refer to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Answer (score 0):

We can pass this in edit function after getting value of id_user

```
<a onclick="edit($(this))" id_user="123" href="#" >Edit</a>

  function edit(obj){
    var id_user = obj.attr("id_user");
    alert(  obj.attr("id_user"));
  }
```

Comment: hi @Mahesh Bhatngar I wanna asking again, How can I redirect page to edit_user and bring data id_user after I get data id_user?

Comment: I can be get data id_user, but I have new problem again, I want to pass data id_user can be bring in to edit_user page, how can I bring data id_user to edit_user page, I will show you code edit_user page above@Mahesh Bhatnagar

Comment: ok , means you want to sending user_id  to edit_user function for getting user data ?

Comment: yess... like this, can you help me? @Mahesh Bhatnagar

Comment: That code is not run correctly ??
url : "<?php echo BASE_URL ?>app.php/usermanagement/edit_user",
        data :{id_user:id_user},

Comment: maybe yess.. I confused how I write code for url, I use php native mvc, can you help me? @Mahesh Bhatnagar I want Id_user pass to controller and from controller to edit_user

Comment: @Tina Maya if no problem please tell which framework are you use

Comment: I use php native, but have a controller and view not with the model, because I call the rest service using curl @Mahesh Bhtnagar

Comment: I have invite you @Mahesh Bhatnagar

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the anchor-element to the edit function like this:

```js
function edit(el) {
  var id_user = $(el).attr('id_user');
  console.log(id_user);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="edit(this)" id_user="test" href="#">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to StackOverflow.

The question you have asked says that you want to use jQuery as the click event, but the code you have written is in pure JavaScript. Please try to go through and understand jQuery Click event from their documentation and implement it according to that. I will put both jQuery example and javascript example below.

> if it's written using jQuery only

**jQuery**

```
button.on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id_user'));
})
```

**jQuery HTML component**

```
<button id_user="testing">Change color</button>
```

> if it's written using pure javascript

**JavaScript**

```
function edit(user) {
    alert(user);
}
```

**JavaScript HTML component**

```
<button onclick="edit('testing')">Change color</button>
```

[Read More about jQuery Click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Thank you @Imesh Chandrasiri

Answer (score 0):

I you are willing to add your custom attribute to any HTML element, please use HTML data-* attributes.
The data-* attribute is used to store custom data private to the page or application.

Example :

```
<ul>
  <li id='user' data-id_user="your-cutom-id">Something</li>
</ul>
```

And you will get data like this :

```
$("#user").data( "id_user" ); // you will get your-cutom-id
```

for more reference 
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

try to get the attrid through initiating a class its easier that way.
first initiate a class:

```
<a class="some-class" onclick="edit()" id_user="<? echo $row ['idx']; ?>" href="#" >Edit</a>
```

then call it:

```
Function edit(){
    var id_user = $(".some-class").attr("id_user");
    alert(id_user);


    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url : "<?php echo BASE_URL ?>app.php/usermanagement/edit_user",
        data :{id_user:id_user},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data)
            console.log(data)
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert(err)
        }
    });
}
```