# What are these custom attributes in aliexpress' span attributes? "ae_some_name=" etc

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

```
<span clk_trigger="" ae_project_id="15210" ae_page_type="list" ae_page_area="hand_filter" ae_button_type="sort by" ae_object_value="number_of_orders" class="sort-item active" data-aplus-clk="x2_2c532ee6" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.productlist.0.i7.78ec3987xZpNnG" st_page_id="jipiftvnqmqcabu9171103ffc8171104036f620782">Pedidos</span>
```

I checked and the page is not in quirksmode, and no doctype [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag?rq=1) so what are these attributes on the span links of the [aliexpress](https://es.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&SearchText=phone%20ring%20holder&ltype=wholesale&SortType=total_tranpro_desc&groupsort=1&CatId=0&page=1) site? Some frontend framework imported that somehow doesn't break the document format? I was interested because there was no open in new window option as they are obviously not links. (My question is about the ae- attributes not a dumb question like the data- attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they are internal attributes used for the site for tracking a product. It beats maintaining an API call or an array inside javascript code for each of the items...

```js
const article = document.querySelector('span');
console.log('data attributes which can be accessed');
console.log(article.dataset);
console.log('accessing custom attributes through below method');
console.log(article.getAttribute("ae_project_id"));
console.log('this fetched attribute can be used for various actions!');
```

```html
<span clk_trigger="" ae_project_id="15210" ae_page_type="list" ae_page_area="hand_filter" ae_button_type="sort by" ae_object_value="number_of_orders" class="sort-item active" data-aplus-clk="x2_2c532ee6" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.productlist.0.i7.78ec3987xZpNnG" st_page_id="jipiftvnqmqcabu9171103ffc8171104036f620782">Pedidos</span>
```

Comment: It responds like a spa so the page doesn't reload on clicking, but I never did understand how frontends get around the !DOCTYPE format requirements.

Comment: I.E. Why are the attributes valid html?

Comment: @user5389726598465 Maybe this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag) will help

Comment: It is actually using a react frontend based on my chrome plugin, which I need a refresher on all the components as I last looked at it over a year ago. I suspect frontends actually create their own dtd under the hood but I'm guessing.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Sorry, this is the extent of my knowledge on this subject, hope you find the answer :)