# How to create a Custom CSS Class to apply directly in HTML Tag?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible create a custom class for example:

```
border {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

and apply directly in a tag, without need of `class=""`?

Example: `<div class="row" border></div>`

Comment: What is the point of it? I don't see any advantage.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag) might give you a few ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Study interess, and curious, is it possible?

Comment: `[border] {
  border:1px solid;
}` but you should use a data-attribute *(data-border for instance)*  see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes and  https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to go with `class`.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong, I didnt mean class, but a custom css style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can. But as @G-Cyrillus said in the comments to create a custom attribute in your HTML element it is better to use HTML [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to stick with the HTML standards. Then you can style your element without adding a `class` attribute.

So if you don't want to add it as a `data-attribute` you can style it like this:

```css
[border] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" border></div>
```

And with the `data-attribute` *(Which is the standard one)* you can do the same:

```css
div[data-border] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" data-border></div>
```

Comment: see my comment about the data-attribute made for this kind of use ;) to fullfill your answer.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That is exactly what I want to add. Thank you. I just searching for it.

Comment: I agree with G-Cyrillus, you should probably use a data attribute, e.g. <div class="row" data-border></div>.  Then in css you would just have [data-border] {  width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid }.   See here for details: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be accomplished by using a javascript framework like VueJs or React.
I know, in VueJs it's called a prop that you pass to a child element. Whether or not the prop (border in your case) is passed down, the styling is applied or not.

Comment: Actually, i'm using VUE and Vuetify