# C# How to render a tag helper from string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers

Consider the following `Process` function of a custom TagHelper:

```
public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
    // ...

    var htmlContent = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(htmlContent);
}
```

I can use the following and it will render the nested taghelper:

```
<custom-button>
    <icon name="search" />
</custom-button>
```

However I need something more like this:

```
<custom-button icon="search"></custom-button>
```

That means I need to somehow render the icon taghelper inside the custom-button taghelper. Here's what I tried and failed:

```
public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
    // ...

    // Set the content (first with the icon tag)
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent("<icon name=\"search\" />");

    // Render the icon
    var htmlContent = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();

    // Set the final content
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(htmlContent);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT! Here's the full CustomButtonTagHelper code:**

```
[HtmlTargetElement("custom-button")]
public class CustomButtonTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IFileVersionProvider _fileVersionProvider;

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
    
    public CustomButtonTagHelper(IFileVersionProvider fileVersionProvider)
    {
        _fileVersionProvider = fileVersionProvider;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {

        // ...

        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
        output.TagName = "button";

        // Set the content (first with the icon tag)
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent($"<icon name=\"{this.Icon}\" />");

        // Render the icon
        var htmlContent = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();

        // Set the final content
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(htmlContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you show as your desired result is not a tag helper inside a tag helper.  That's a custom attribute on a tag and it's not following the recommended standard for [custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag)

Comment: @devlincarnate The `icon` attribute will actually go away once the taghelper gets rendered.

Comment: Also, you've left out the relevant code segment(s)...we need to see what's happening in those methods that are called inside of the `Process()` method, and then you also need to  provide sample input so we know what gets passed to `Process()`'

Comment: @devlincarnate I don't pass anything to `Process()`, I don't even call it. This is all handled by razor (I guess).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add attribute to Custom TagHelper,you can try to set [output.Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.taghelperoutput.attributes?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperOutput_Attributes).
Here is a demo:

```
public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
            {


                output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
                output.TagName = "button";
                output.Attributes.Add("icon", Icon);
               
            }
```

View:

```
<custom-button icon="search"></custom-button>
```

Rendered Html:

```
<button icon="search"></button>
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What you actually want?You say you need`<custom-button icon="search"></custom-button>`rather than `<custom-button>
    <icon name="search" />
</custom-button>`,so you cannot set SetHtmlContent.

Comment: That's what I want to write, not to generate. Please read the question again.

Comment: You want to write `<custom-button icon="search"></custom-button>` or `<custom-button>
    <icon name="search" />
</custom-button>`?And what you want to generate ?